# Error when cloning git "shallow" repository

Tags: git

I'm getting the following error when issuing the command `git clone --bare /path/to/repo`:

`fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository`

First, what is a shallow repository and why doesn't it let me clone it?

Comment: For record, no longer a restriction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/171950

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shallow repository is a repository which does not contain the full history.

See the [git-clone manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> --depth
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified
>   number of revisions. A shallow
>   repository has a number of limitations
>   (you cannot clone or fetch from it,
>   nor push from nor into it), but is
>   adequate if you are only interested in
>   the recent history of a large project
>   with a long history, and would want to
>   send in fixes as patches.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I have "lost" the original repository. Is it possible to turn my shallow repo into a normal one?

Comment: Well, I deleted the .git/shallow file and it seems to be working. Hope it didn't break anything.

Comment: Create a new repository and import your codebase into it. If you only have a shallow repo you've already lost your history anyway so re-importing your code into a new repo won't make you lose anything.

Comment: You could also remove the `.git/shallow` file. I do not know if that has any negative side-effects though.

Comment: @Oliver: Examine the "root" commit of your repository; you should probably see that it thinks it has a parent, but that that parent commit doesn't actually exist in your repository. This could easily cause problems. For example, when I create a shallow clone and remove the .git/shallow file, git log runs into that oldest commit, can't find its parent, and dies: `fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit ...`.

Answer (score 8):

Rename .git/shallow to something else, clone, rename it back, copy .git/shallow to cloned repository