# Is it safe to shallow clone with --depth 1, create commits, and pull updates again?

Tags: performance, git, git-clone

The `--depth 1` option in [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Create a *shallow* clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

But I've successfully done a shallow clone, committed some changes **and pushed those changes** back to the (bare clone) origin.

It makes sense to me - I mean why not? when the cloned HEAD is identifiable in the origin, and my commit comes on top of this, there seems no reason. But the manual says otherwise.

I like the idea of shallow clone - e.g. of drupal core: there's no way I need to know what went on in drupal 4 when I've started from 7. - but I don't want to shoot myself in the foot.

So is it safe to shallow clone, develop commits in it, pull again to keep up with updates from origin?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone) was a decent discussion on clone depth

Comment: Yes, I'd read that too, thanks Andy. the `--orphan` concept seems similar and I intend to have a play. Still bit unnerved that the docs don't match the reality [because who's to say the docs for `--orphan` are correct?!]

Comment: Found another [great discussion of working with a truncated history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724522/creating-github-repository-with-only-a-subset-of-a-local-repositorys-history/5724782#5724782). But it doesn't help me.

Comment: Git 1.9 (Q1 2014) will fully support shallow repo cloning! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309)

Comment: Git 2.5 (Q2 2015) supports a single fetch commit! I have edited my answer, referencing "[Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)".

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Note that Git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014) has *removed* that limitation.
See [commit 82fba2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82fba2b9d39163a0c9b7a3a2f35964cbc039e1a), from [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

> Now that git supports data transfer from or to a shallow clone, these limitations are not true anymore.

The [documentation now reads](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82fba2b9d39163a0c9b7a3a2f35964cbc039e1aa/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L182-L184):

```
--depth <depth>::
```

> Create a 'shallow' clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.

That stems from commits like [0d7d285](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d7d285f0e29abb994fe32db87ee81b00f403bd2), [f2c681c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2c681cf12c54ce3859b36693f8a13c36126577b), and [c29a7b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c29a7b8b3f71c1bede1f57626bafe120280aaea3) which support clone, send-pack /receive-pack with/from shallow clones.
[smart-http now supports shallow fetch/clone too](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16094885ca94f72abc28a915f9aa4021e203a16d).

All the details are in "[`shallow.c`: the 8 steps to select new commits for `.git/shallow`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58babfffdeeecaa4d6edecaac1fb0c595218b801)".

Update June 2015: [Git 2.5 will even allow for **fetching a single commit**!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)
(Ultimate shallow case)

---

Update January 2016: Git 2.8 (Mach 2016) now documents officially the practice of getting a minimal history.
See [commit 99487cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99487cf228ecba869d2f87f1b55f281fdd1342db), [commit 9cfde9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cfde9ee8f6dc82365f1e977935960f34108076b) (30 Dec 2015), [commit 9cfde9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cfde9ee8f6dc82365f1e977935960f34108076b) (30 Dec 2015), [commit bac5874](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bac58749bb2cd04720a4d5a1f58ebc428869f9a2) (29 Dec 2015), and [commit 1de2e44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1de2e442af45acf52ad45f9ac86d4c19f6475590) (28 Dec 2015) by [Stephen P. Smith (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7e3e80a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e3e80a88181c99d33567c05fc865e26f971e954), 20 Jan 2016)</sup>

This is "[`Documentation/user-manual.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9cfde9ee8f6dc82365f1e977935960f34108076b/Documentation/user-manual.txt#L2131-L2149)"

> A `<<def_shallow_clone,shallow clone>>` is created by specifying the [`git-clone --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) switch.
>   The depth can later be changed with the [`git-fetch --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) switch, or full history restored with `--unshallow`.
>
> Merging inside a `<<def_shallow_clone,shallow clone>>` will work as long as a merge base is in the recent history.
>   Otherwise, it will be like merging unrelated histories and may have to result in huge conflicts.
>   This limitation may make such a repository unsuitable to be used in merge based workflows.

Update 2020:

- git 2.11.1 introduced option `git fetch --shallow-exclude=` to prevent fetching all history
- git 2.11.1 introduced option `git fetch --shallow-since=` to prevent fetching old commits.

---

For more on the shallow clone update process, see "[How to update a git shallow clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369314/6309)".

---

As commented by [Richard Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420947/richard-michael):

> to backfill history: **`git pull --unshallow`**

And [Olle Härstedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138090/olle-h%C3%A4rstedt) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga/21217267?noredirect=1#comment82025001_21217267):

> To backfill *part* of the history: **`git fetch --depth=100`**.

Comment: So much text just to say "**yes**, as long as your git version isn't 4+ years old and the merge base is in the recent history"

Comment: @Boris this answer help me a lot since i was sceptical of using shallow clone. Previously it breaks sometimes when I'm doing a commit and merge. this answer is a brief history, of why it is now works when it happen, and how to properly do it.

Comment: My requirement is that after a shallow clone I need to commit this code to a new remote repository .. I cannot --unshallow it due to the huge size of this code. .. How can I push this shallow clone to a new repo without any issues (currently facing Shallow object update failed issue) .. Any ideas pls

Comment: @Tiny i would recommend a separate local repository, which would reference your shallow clone folder. Can you ask a separate question ?

Answer (score 6):

See some of the answers to my similar question [why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone) and the link to the recent thread on the git list.

Ultimately, the 'depth' measurement isn't consistent between repos, because they measure from their individual HEADs, rather than (a) your Head, or (b) the commit(s) you cloned/fetched, or (c) something else you had in mind.

The hard bit is getting one's Use Case right (i.e. self-consistent), so that distributed, and therefore probably divergent repos will still work happily together.

It does look like the `checkout --orphan` is the right 'set-up' stage, but still lacks clean (i.e. a simple understandable one line command) guidance on the "clone" step. Rather it looks like you have to `init` a repo, set up a `remote` tracking branch (you do want the one branch only?), and then `fetch` that single branch, which feels long winded with more opportunity for mistakes.

Edit: For the 'clone' step see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git/4146786#4146786)

Comment: Tanks Philip. Fetching a remote branch will still pull in the entire history (AFAIK). You're right about relative depths, really I want some suitable point in history (like git merge-base 7.x 7.0 in my case)

Comment: @artfulrobot: the '--orphan' method allows you to create a short narrow 'clone' (i.e. a focussed segment) and then use it as if it was a proper repo. It's something I haven't tried in anger yet but it's something I need to prove soon.