# Git: How to Archive from remote repository directly?

Tags: git

I usually use the command below inside my `project.git` to get an archive in the specified destinations:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /home/kave/site/
```

I wonder if its possible to archive directly from a remote repository instead into a destination directory?

I tried something like this, without any joy:

```
git archive master https://kave@dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/myoproject.git | tar -x -C /home/kave/site/
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014) will be much more efficient with shallow cloning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217326/6309

Comment: For GitHub repositories, you might consider [`gh repo archive <repository>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69576856/6309).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [`git help archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive):

```
   --remote=<repo>
       Instead of making a tar archive from the local repository, retrieve a tar archive from a remote repository.
```

Command should end up like:

```
$ git archive --remote=https://kave@dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/myoproject.git master
```

But, if you would just extract the repo, you can make a shallow clone using `--depth` parameter of `git clone`:

```
   --depth <depth>
       Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.
```

So you have something like this:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 https://kave@dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/myoproject.git
```

Comment: How can I make `git clone --depth=1` pull a specific tag instead of master?

Comment: @Robru: That deserves to be a standalone question, I think, but read about `--[no-]single-branch` in `git help clone`. Something like `git clone --depth=1 --single-branch --branch TARGET_BRANCH REMOTE_URL`, I think. And, thanks - I've never thought about that before :)

Comment: Can't archive from Github: `You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.`  You can look up this [article](https://www.gilesorr.com/blog/git-archive-github.html) for more details.

Comment: You might also get an error `fatal: operation not supported by protocol` when trying to archive from Github over HTTP. The solution is the same as in the article linked by @SiminJie : Github offers a tarball download service, so use that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, specifically for GitHub, is [`github-backup`](https://pypi.org/project/github-backup/). It has options to capture GitHub-specific features like issues, wikis, and so on. Here is an example command-line I used recently to make archives of some other people's repositories:

```
github-backup --all --pull-details --prefer-ssh --repository REPO REPO-OWNER -u mhucka
```

In the command above, *REPO-OWNER* stands for the owner of the target repository and *REPO* is the repository name.