# How to download (just the files) from another user's private Github repo using the command line on a Mac OS X?

Tags: bash, git, unix, github, command-line

I am on a Mac OS X Mojave. From the command line, I want to access a ***private*** repo (which I do not own but have access to) located at

```
https://github.com/<ORG_NAME>/<PROJECT-NAME>
```

By "access," I mean that I only need to download the project directory to my local machine. I only need the files and directory structure. I do not need to checkout the repo or get the .git history.

How can I do this from the command line?

[This question is different because it deals with the scenario where I own the repo.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2505096/1640892) Which I don't. Also that question uses the `clone` command. And I don't need a clone to checkout or the git history. I just need a copy of the files as previously stated.

[This answer suggests the following.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710270/1640892)

```
git clone https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<ORG_NAME>/<PROJECT-NAME>.git
```

But they said you need to enter info at the prompt. I would like to avoid entering info at the prompt because this is part of a larger automation routine I'm making. So I'd like to have the command line instructions self-contained.

Edit: [I also found this additional information,](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-clone-other-private-repos/4331) but I still can't figure it out from there.

Comment: A deploy key may help with your permissions question https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys. It may help to describe what you are trying to do in case there is another solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368837/copy-a-git-repo-without-history

Comment: You can try to [download the entire repo as zip from hithub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857787/7976758) or you can use [`git archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751126/7976758).