# How to zip github repository in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am, obviously, still quite new to VSC but I have added github extensions and can edit in VSC rather than github WebUI now.

When I want to test the code (a KODI plugin) I simply need a zip of all the files in that repo. On github I would just select *Code - Download Zip*.
Is there a way of doing this without going to the github website and without downloading and then manually compressing in File Explorer?

I would like to directly create a zip from the selected folders within VSC.

Thank you for your help
Alex

Comment: go to your OS file explorer, select all files/folders except the `.git` folder and right click and select to create zip file

Answer (score 1):

You can download or create a zip archive from an existing repo, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750182/git-how-to-archive-from-remote-repository-directly).

If you want to integrate this with VSCode check out [how to create a VSCode Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

Comment: Thank you Jorge for your reply.
Unfortunately that would be one task per repo and branch I am working on. I would like to be able to use it without each time cahnging repo and branch manually.

Comment: @AleXSR700 you can create a system wide task or one for each new gh codespace created or, also, one profile-wide (i am not 1100% sure about the last one).