# What is the git clone --filter option's syntax?

Tags: git

The Git 2.17 [changelog](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.17.0.txt) describes this option:

> - The machinery to clone & fetch, which in turn involves packing and 
>     unpacking objects, has been told how to omit certain objects using
>     the filtering mechanism introduced by another topic.  It now knows
>     to mark the resulting pack as a promisor pack to tolerate missing
>     objects, laying foundation for "narrow" clones.

Is this flag ready to be used, or is it most likely quite unstable? Does anyone know the right syntax to pass? Whatever flags I pass are rejected as being an invalid filter-spec. For example, these were my attempts to filter by directory:

```
git clone file://path --depth=1 --filter '--subdirectory-filter Assets' TestRepo
git clone file://path --depth=1 --filter --subdirectory-filter Assets TestRepo
git clone file://path --depth=1 --filter Assets TestRepo
```

Comment: A concrete example of "what `blob:` does can be seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934 `--filter=combine:` also shown there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The format for filter-spec is defined in the options section of `git rev-list --help`. You can also [see it in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---filterltfilter-specgt).  Here's what it currently says:

> #### --filter=<filter-spec>
>
> Only useful with one of the --objects*; omits objects (usually blobs) from the list of printed objects. The <filter-spec> may be one of the following:
>
> The form `--filter=blob:none` omits all blobs.
>
> The form `--filter=blob:limit=<n>[kmg]` omits blobs larger than n bytes or units. n may be zero. The suffixes k, m, and g can be used to name units in KiB, MiB, or GiB. For example, blob:limit=1k is the same as blob:limit=1024.
>
> The form `--filter=sparse:oid=<blob-ish>` uses a sparse-checkout specification contained in the blob (or blob-expression) <blob-ish> to omit blobs that would not be required for a sparse checkout on the requested refs.

Comment: Thanks! That option is less useful than I had hoped. (It can't be used to combine `clone` and `filter-branch`.)

Comment: You want [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) for that. It's described quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613578/3195526) and in more detail [here, with a useful example](https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html).

Comment: By using the --filter option, Can I download only one specific directory?

Comment: No. Filtering limits commits, not files. You can use `--sparse` to get only the root directory, then edit the sparse checkout file to add the directory you want.
Or you can use `--depth=1` to get all files but with no history, which will at least make the clone much smaller.

Comment: @PaulHicks actually, `--filter=blob:none` will exclude all files from the `clone` and only fetch the commits, which combined with `--depth=1` results in only a single object.

Comment: Note: the documentation has changed a bit with [Git 2.44 (Q1 2024)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f50984cf4e1c7562cd96a4064dcdfef181d6b97)

Answer (score 19):

> What is the `git clone --filter` option's syntax?

This is at least clearer with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020)

Before that, here is a quick TLDR; example of that command, combined with a [(cone) sparse-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309):

```sh
#fastest clone possible:
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/git/git
cd git
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

That will bring back only the top folder files, excluding by default any subfolder.
The initial clone remains faster, because of the `git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout` step.

---

Now, onto that `git clone --filter` option's syntax:

See [commit 4a46544](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a465443a6ce51bd6e1d4ffef56d3f2e8d45f506) (22 Mar 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa0c1eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa0c1eb45170d3e4b80eb6805f9466baf1eef1fd), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a465443a6ce51bd6e1d4ffef56d3f2e8d45f506): document `--filter` options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> It turns out that the "`--filter=<filter-spec>`" option is not documented anywhere in the "`git clone`" page, and instead is detailed carefully in "git rev-list" where it serves a different purpose.
>
> Add a small bit about this option in the documentation. It would be worth some time to create a subsection in the "git clone" documentation about partial clone as a concept and how it can be a surprising experience. For example, "git checkout" will likely trigger a pack download.

The [git clone documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4a465443a6ce51bd6e1d4ffef56d3f2e8d45f506/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L166-L174) now includes:

> ### `--filter=<filter-spec>`:

> Use the partial clone feature and request that the server sends a subset of reachable objects according to a given object filter.
>
> When using `--filter`, the supplied `<filter-spec>` is used for the partial clone filter.
>
> For example, `--filter=blob:none` will filter out all blobs (file contents) until needed by Git.
> Also, `--filter=blob:limit=<size>` will filter out all blobs of size at least `<size>`.

For more details on filter specifications, see the `--filter` option in [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---filterltfilter-specgt).

---

> That option is less useful than I had hoped. (It can't be used to combine `clone` and `filter-branch`).

And yet this filtering mechanism is the extension of one associated with clone, for implementing the [partial cloning (or narrow clone) introduced in Dec. 2017 with Git 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48012038/6309).

But your Git repo hosting server must support the **[protocol v2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273976/6309)**, supported for now (Oct. 2018) [only by GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462372/6309).

Meaning you can use `--filter` with `git clone`, as a recent Git 2.20 patch illustrates (see below).

That filter was then added to `git fetch` in [this patch series](https://public-inbox.org/git/cover.1506714999.git.jonathantanmy@google.com/).
It is part of [a new pack-protocol capability "`filter`", added to the fetch-pack and
upload-pack negotiation.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c4df23f7927d8d00e666a3c8d1b3375f1dc8a3c1/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt#L70-L89)
See ["filter" in Documentation/technical/pack-protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c4df23f7927d8d00e666a3c8d1b3375f1dc8a3c1/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt#L285-L290), which refers to [the rev-list options](https://github.com/git/git/blob/caf3827e2f6a8a0315301d52b5bf46e269b3a388/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L710-L730).

---

With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), a partial clone that is configured to lazily fetch missing objects will on-demand issue a "`git fetch`" request to the originating
repository to fill not-yet-obtained objects.
The request has been optimized for requesting a tree object (and not the leaf blob
objects contained in it) by telling the originating repository that
no blobs are needed.

See [commit 4c7f956](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c7f9567ea2628451a0f4ad52599a25d34657bae), [commit 12f19a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12f19a9825686e3641803580bda4e2ab2abd44ed) (03 Oct 2018) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa54ccc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa54cccf1ffcf4b49076d24062f3592b73e2bb84), 19 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `fetch-pack`: exclude blobs when lazy-fetching trees

> A partial clone with missing trees can be obtained using "**`git clone --filter=tree:none <repo>`**".
> In such a repository, when a tree needs to be lazily fetched, any tree or blob it directly or indirectly references is fetched as well, regardless of whether the original command required those objects, or if the local repository already had some of them.
>
> This is because the fetch protocol, which the lazy fetch uses, does not
> allow clients to request that only the wanted objects be sent, which
> would be the ideal solution. This patch implements a partial solution:
> specify the "blob:none" filter, somewhat reducing the fetch payload.
>
> This change has no effect when lazily fetching blobs (due to how filters
> work). And if lazily fetching a commit (such repositories are difficult
> to construct and is not a use case we support very well, but it is
> possible), referenced commits and trees are still fetched - only the
> blobs are not fetched.

You can see further optimization with:

See [commit e70a303](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e70a3030e747312327a4f3619247bf8a986aa577), [commit 6ab4055](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ab4055775b0e560d1f2a1be2e7251d872874655), [commit 0177565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01775651481ecd9c7288a85cfb7999f7f38ab37c), [commit 99bcb88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99bcb883cb2bd2d27939a831a66d794770427e98) (27 Sep 2018) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0527fba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0527fbab689929de47ab3fa7baf1e7618ffa704f), 19 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### transport: allow skipping of ref listing

> The `get_refs_via_connect()` function both performs the handshake
> (including determining the protocol version) and obtaining the list of
> remote refs.
>
> However, the fetch protocol v2 supports fetching objects without the listing of refs, so make it possible for the user to **skip the listing** by creating a new `handshake()` function.

---

Note the syntax has changed/evolved with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) and its update of the protocol message specification to allow only the limited use of scaled quantities.
This is ensure potential compatibility issues will not go out of hand.

See [commit 87c2d9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87c2d9d3102e6c388f2d29f1bdb0b3a222d9a707) (08 Jan 2019) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
See [commit 8272f26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8272f26034c9dbaf5cd216a137b8e91241cbc24e), [commit c813a7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c813a7c35f44f4bf435c6ecb21bf4b9ec8f227de) (09 Jan 2019) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 073312b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/073312b4c7a15d484d2ffdc2eb4a406df9cf9c55), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `filter-options`: expand scaled numbers

> When communicating with a remote server or a subprocess, use
> expanded numbers rather than numbers with scaling suffix in the
> object filter spec (e.g.  "`limit:blob=1k`" becomes "`limit:blob=1024`").
>
> Update the protocol docs to note that clients should always perform this expansion, to allow for more compatibility between server
> implementations.

---

As an aside, Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) consider the "`invalid filter-spec`" message is user-facing and not a BUG, so it makes localizeable.

See [commit 5c03bc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c03bc8b1d1f992ebe43c567bb95cdb5e0273d28) (31 May 2019) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ca02d36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca02d3669f3db502efaa9cb5a41a825c532cbabe), 21 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `list-objects-filter-options`: error is localizeable

> The "`invalid filter-spec`" message is user-facing and not a BUG, so make
> it localizeable.
>
> For reference, the message appears in this context:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list --filter=blob:nonse --objects HEAD
> fatal: invalid filter-spec 'blob:nonse'
> ```

---

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), the http transport, which lacked some optimization the native transports learned to avoid unnecessary ref advertisement, has been fixed.

See [commit fddf2eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fddf2ebe388f3a11013c14ebe012dee520caa9ff), [commit ac3fda8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac3fda82bfe1c9e99c5838d052c678c78139ee34) (21 Aug 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f67bf53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f67bf53300ac7bd57a593a3ec2338050ea8343f1), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### transport-helper: skip ls-refs if unnecessary

> [Commit e70a303](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e70a3030e747312327a4f3619247bf8a986aa577) ("`fetch`: do not list refs if fetching only hashes",
> 2018-10-07, Git v2.20.0-rc0) and its ancestors taught Git, as an optimization, to skip the `ls-refs` step when it is not necessary during a protocol v2 fetch
> (for example, when lazy fetching a missing object in a partial clone, or
> when running "`git fetch --no-tags <remote> <SHA-1>`").
> But that was only done for natively supported protocols; in particular, HTTP was not supported.
>
> Teach Git to skip `ls-refs` when using remote helpers that support connect
> or stateless-connect.

---

Another optimization in Git 2.24 (Q4 2019)

See [commit d8bc1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8bc1a518accaecde83b50288c4591f838401162) (08 Oct 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7d2ced](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7d2cedec27560caec9283e73759a734154cf505), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`send-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8bc1a518accaecde83b50288c4591f838401162): never fetch when checking exclusions
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> When building the packfile to be sent, `send_pack()` is given a list of remote refs to be used as exclusions.
> For each ref, it first checks if the ref exists locally, and if it does, passes it with a "`^`" prefix to `pack-objects`.
> **However, in a partial clone, the check may trigger a lazy fetch**.
>
> The additional commit ancestry information obtained during such fetches may show that certain objects that would have been sent are already known to the server, resulting in a smaller pack being sent.
> But this is at the cost of fetching from many possibly unrelated refs, and the lazy fetches do not help at all in the typical case where the client is up-to-date with the upstream of the branch being pushed.
>
> Ensure that these lazy fetches do not occur.

---

Finally, Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) includes a last-minute work-around for a lazy fetch glitch, which illustrates one usage of the `filter` syntax.

See [commit c7aadcc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7aadccba01579d8ab23e662b3b64bc6cc2980a7) (23 Oct 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c32ca69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c32ca691c282fb34eeb29639340a2aa15f861606), 04 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7aadccba01579d8ab23e662b3b64bc6cc2980a7): delay `fetch_if_missing=0` until after config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> Suppose, from a repository that has "`.gitmodules`", we clone with `--filter=blob:none`:
>
> ```
> git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout \
> https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/git/git
> ```
>
> Then we fetch:
>
> ```
> git -C git fetch
> ```
>
> This will cause a "**`unable to load config blob object`**", because the `fetch_config_from_gitmodules()` invocation in `cmd_fetch()` will attempt to load "`.gitmodules`" (which Git knows to exist because the client has the tree of HEAD) while `fetch_if_missing` is set to 0.
>
> `fetch_if_missing` is set to 0 too early - "`.gitmodules`" here should be lazily fetched.
>
> Git must set `fetch_if_missing` to 0 before the fetch because as part of the fetch, packfile negotiation happens (and we do not want to fetch any missing objects when checking existence of objects), but we do not need to set it so early.
> Move the setting of `fetch_if_missing` to the earliest possible point in `cmd_fetch()`, right before any fetching happens.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), debugging support for lazy cloning has been a bit improved.
`git fetch` v2 now makes good use of promisor files.

See [commit 5374a29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa) (15 Oct 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 026587c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/026587c79365aa7d204e4b4ee70ca9dbb181d688), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa): write fetched refs to `.promisor`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> The specification of promisor packfiles (in [`partial-clone.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt)) states that the `.promisor` files that accompany packfiles do not matter (just like `.keep` files), so whenever a packfile is fetched from the promisor remote, Git has been writing empty `.promisor` files.
> But these files could contain more useful information.
>
> So instead of writing empty files, write the refs fetched to these files.
>
> This makes it easier to debug issues with partial clones, as we can identify what refs (and their associated hashes) were fetched at the time the packfile was downloaded, and if necessary, compare those hashes against what the promisor remote reports now.
>
> This is implemented by teaching `fetch-pack` to write its own non-empty `.promisor` file whenever it knows the name of the pack's lockfile.
> This covers the case wherein the user runs "`git fetch`" with an internal protocol or HTTP protocol v2 (`fetch_refs_via_pack()` in [`transport.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa/transport.c) sets `lock_pack`) and with HTTP protocol v0/v1 (`fetch_git()` in [`remote-curl.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa/remote-curl.c) passes "`--lock-pack`" to "`fetch-pack`").

---

Before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), fetching from a lazily cloned repository resulted at the server side in attempts to lazy fetch objects that the client side has, many of which will not be available from the third-party anyway.

See [commit 77aa094](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77aa0941ce8ac2dc0027f85e0c79632034cd47f0) (16 Jul 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 37f382a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37f382a924f2cb658f7b61036b2fc9fe1314d3a6), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77aa0941ce8ac2dc0027f85e0c79632034cd47f0): do not lazy-fetch "`have`" objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> When `upload-pack` receives a request containing "`have`" hashes, it (among other things) checks if the served repository has the corresponding objects. However, it does not do so with the `OBJECT_INFO_SKIP_FETCH_OBJECT` flag, so if serving a partial clone, a lazy fetch will be triggered first.
>
> This was discovered at `$DAYJOB` when a user fetched from a partial clone (into another partial clone - although this would also happen if the repo to be fetched into is not a partial clone).
>
> Therefore, whenever "`have`" hashes are checked for existence, pass the `OBJECT_INFO_SKIP_FETCH_OBJECT` flag.
> Also add the `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK` flag to improve performance, as it is typical that such objects do not exist in the serving repo, and the consequences of a false negative are minor (usually, a slightly larger pack sent).

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the component to respond to "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73a925516604df7a95ad69b8d650275eb4ab270f/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> request is made more configurable to selectively allow or reject object filtering specification used for partial cloning.

See [commit 6cc275e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cc275ea56e21537f480443fc8fd36f34c8b92cd) (05 Aug 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 5b01a4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b01a4e8ff19fa9797a67b53df2db0a1a574fe81), [commit 6dd3456](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243) (03 Aug 2020), and [commit b9ea214](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9ea214795b89e0455bbe92fab5d30d1f3a4cc6d) (31 Jul 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 73a9255](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73a925516604df7a95ad69b8d650275eb4ab270f), 11 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243): allow banning certain object filter(s)
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Git clients may ask the server for a partial set of objects, where the set of objects being requested is refined by one or more object filters. Server administrators can configure '[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> ' to allow or ban these filters by setting the '`uploadpack.allowFilter`' variable to '`true`' or '`false`', respectively.
>
> However, administrators using bitmaps may wish to allow certain kinds of object filters, but ban others. Specifically, they may wish to allow object filters that can be optimized by the use of bitmaps, while rejecting other object filters which aren't and represent a perceived performance degradation (as well as an increased load factor on the server).
>
> Allow configuring '[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> ' to support object filters on a case-by-case basis by introducing two new configuration variables:
>
> - '`uploadpackfilter.allow`'
> - '`uploadpackfilter.<kind>.allow`'
>
> where '' may be one of '`blobNone`', '`blobLimit`', '`tree`', and so on.
>
> Setting the second configuration variable for any valid value of '`<kind>`' explicitly allows or disallows restricting that kind of object filter.
>
> If a client requests the object filter `<kind>` and the respective configuration value is not set, '[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> ' will default to the value of '`uploadpackfilter.allow`', which itself defaults to '`true`' to maintain backwards compatibility.
> Note that this differs from '`uploadpack.allowfilter`', which controls whether or not the '`filter`' capability is advertised.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243/Documentation/config/uploadpack.txt#L12):

> ### uploadpackfilter.allow
>
> Provides a default value for unspecified object filters (see: the
> below configuration variable).
> Defaults to `true`.

> ### `uploadpackfilter.<filter>.allow`
>
> Explicitly allow or ban the object filter corresponding to
> `<filter>`, where `<filter>` may be one of: `blob:none`,
> `blob:limit`, `tree`, `sparse:oid`, or `combine`.
> If using
> combined filters, both `combine` and all of the nested filter
> kinds must be allowed.
> Defaults to `uploadpackfilter.allow`.

---

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), Fix potential server side resource deallocation issues when responding to a partial clone request.

See [commit 8d133f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d133f500a5390a089988141cdec8154a732764d), [commit aab179d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aab179d937379e28c67dcab0a46fdba05c11d919) (03 Dec 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 21127fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21127fa9829da1f7b805e44517970194490567d0), 17 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d133f500a5390a089988141cdec8154a732764d): don't free `allowed_filters` util pointers
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> To keep track of which object filters are allowed or not, '[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d133f500a5390a089988141cdec8154a732764d/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> stores the name of each filter in a `string_list,` and sets it `->util` pointer to be either 0 or 1, indicating whether it is banned or allowed.
>
> Later on, we attempt to clear that list, but we incorrectly ask for the util pointers to be free()'d, too. This behavior (introduced back in [6dd3456a8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dd3456a8ccbad6a0a6a31bc7192025617114243) ("`[`upload-pack.c`](https`://github.com/git/git/blob/8d133f500a5390a089988141cdec8154a732764d/upload-pack.c): allow banning certain object filter(s)", 2020-08-03, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73a925516604df7a95ad69b8d650275eb4ab270f) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7814e8a05a59c0cf5fb186661d1551c75d1299b5))) leads to an invalid free, and causes us to crash.
>
> In order to trigger this, one needs to fetch from a server that
> (a) has at least one object filter allowed, and
> (b) issue a fetch that contains a subset of the allowed filters (i.e., we cannot ask for a banned filter, since this causes us to `die()` before we hit the bogus `string_list_clear()`).
>
> In that case, whatever banned filters exist will cause a noop `free()` (since those `->util` pointers are set to 0), but the first allowed filter we try to free will crash us.
>
> We never noticed this in the tests because we didn't have an example of setting 'uploadPackFilter' configuration variables and then following up with a valid fetch. The first new '[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d133f500a5390a089988141cdec8154a732764d/Documentation/git-clone.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> prevents further regression here. For good measure on top, add a test which checks the same behavior at a tree depth greater than 0.

---

A recent "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f4f7304b443a52af9fdbbf15092516c061de4aeb/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> fix left a temporary directory behind when the transport layer returned an failure.
That has been corrected with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021).

See [commit 6aacb7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6aacb7d8619c50b3c92fe3e99b93ffa9b6065dfc) (19 May 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4f7304](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4f7304b443a52af9fdbbf15092516c061de4aeb), 14 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6aacb7d8619c50b3c92fe3e99b93ffa9b6065dfc): clean up directory after `transport_fetch_refs()` failure
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> [`git-clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6aacb7d8619c50b3c92fe3e99b93ffa9b6065dfc/Documentation/git-clone.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> started respecting errors from the transport subsystem in [aab179d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aab179d937379e28c67dcab0a46fdba05c11d919) ("[`builtin/clone.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aab179d937379e28c67dcab0a46fdba05c11d919/builtin/clone.c): don't ignore `transport_fetch_refs()` errors", 2020-12-03, Git v2.30.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21127fa9829da1f7b805e44517970194490567d0)).
> However, that commit didn't handle the cleanup of the filesystem quite right.
>
> The cleanup of the directory that `cmd_clone()` creates is done by an `atexit()` handler, which we control with a flag.
> It starts as `JUNK_LEAVE_NONE` ("clean up everything"), then progresses to `JUNK_LEAVE_REPO` when we know we have a valid repo but not working tree, and then finally `JUNK_LEAVE_ALL` when we have a successful checkout.

Comment: This answer is so verbose as to be depleted of any value except to serve as a use case for character limitations.

Comment: I appreciated the thoroughness of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

## `git clone --filter`: *submodule* edition.

(see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309) for the regular repository `git clone --filter`)

The notion of partial clone for **submodule** (sparse checkout) has started to come along:

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), this lazy/partial `clone --filter` works even with a submodule, when `transfer.fsckobjects` is set.

See [commit 1b03df5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b03df5f1e98b64b3bdc8a59c56697eaf675daca) (20 Aug 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 63728e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63728e481451b8e218bec4d21ce085471d90fe7a), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b03df5f1e98b64b3bdc8a59c56697eaf675daca): in partial clone, pass `--promisor`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> When fetching a pack from a promisor remote, the corresponding `.promisor` file needs to be created.
> "`fetch-pack`" originally did this by passing "`--promisor`" to "`index-pack`", but in [5374a290aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa) ("`fetch-pack`: write fetched refs to .promisor", 2019-10-16, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/026587c79365aa7d204e4b4ee70ca9dbb181d688) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41)), "fetch-pack" was taught to do this itself instead, because it needed to store ref information in the `.promisor` file.
>
> This causes a problem with superprojects when transfer.fsckobjects is set, because in the current implementation, it is "`index-pack`" that calls `fsck_finish()` to check the objects; before [5374a290aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5374a290aa56390f9f44547d52f8f30fb2e866aa), `fsck_finish()` would see that `.gitmodules` is a promisor object and tolerate it being missing, but after, there is no `.promisor` file (at the time of the invocation of `fsck_finish()` by "`index-pack`") to tell it that `.gitmodules` is a promisor object, so it returns an error.
>
> Therefore, teach "`fetch-pack`" to pass "`--promisor`" to index pack once again.
> "`fetch-pack`" will subsequently overwrite this file with the ref information.
>
> An alternative is to instead move object checking to "`fetch-pack`", and let "`index-pack`" only index the files.
> However, since "`index-pack`" has to inflate objects in order to index them, it seems reasonable to also let it check the objects (which also require inflated files).

---

[Reminder](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ddf593a250e07d388059f7e3f471078e1d2ed5c/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt#L28-L46=):

> Partial clone allows us to avoid downloading such unneeded objects *in advance* during clone and fetch operations and thereby reduce download times and disk usage.
> Missing objects can later be "demand fetched" if/when needed.
>
> A remote that can later provide the missing objects is called a
> **promisor remote**, as it promises to send the objects when
> requested.
> Initially Git supported only one promisor remote, the `origin`
> remote from which the user cloned and that was configured in the
> "`extensions.partialClone`" config option.
> Later support for more than one promisor remote has been implemented.
>
> Use of partial clone requires that the user be online and the origin
> remote or other promisor remotes be available for on-demand fetching
> of missing objects.
> This may or may not be problematic for the user.
>
> For example, if the user can stay within the pre-selected subset of
> the source tree, they may not encounter any missing objects.
>
> Alternatively, the user could try to pre-fetch various objects if they know that they are going offline.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), prepare the internals for lazily fetching objects in submodules from their promisor remotes.

See [commit ef830cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef830cc4341260ef45ffe6c7164e23505d45a5a2), [commit d1fa943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1fa94356ddd2a81348532d49030cd08d0df6a4d), [commit 69bb2e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69bb2e1804d2f3e5ba7ef365fdfd1937b4d7ca0a), [commit ef7dc2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef7dc2e9ccb832c1dc29d5102c09f6c4a51d4dca), [commit ebaf3bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebaf3bcf1aecdc31062ede80fca3a7c98202d8bb) (17 Jun 2021) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8721e2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8721e2eaedd0290ef399f638912a49b36402e715), 16 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`promisor-remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef830cc4341260ef45ffe6c7164e23505d45a5a2): teach lazy-fetch in any repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> This is one step towards supporting partial clone submodules.
>
> Even after this patch, we will still lack partial clone submodules support, primarily because a lot of Git code that accesses submodule objects does so by adding their object stores as alternates, meaning that any lazy fetches that would occur in the submodule would be done based on the config of the superproject, not of the submodule.
> This also prevents testing of the functionality in this patch by user-facing commands.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git clone --filter=... --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2e65591ed61ab488395c454004106a5e9424648e/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L175)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt))</sup>" only makes the top-level a partial clone, while submodules are fully cloned.
This behaviour is changed to pass the same filter down to the submodules.

See [commit f05da2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655) (04 Feb 2022) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2e65591](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e65591ed61ab488395c454004106a5e9424648e), 25 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`clone, submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655): pass partial clone filters to submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> When cloning a repo with a `--filter` and with `--recurse-submodules` enabled, the partial clone filter only applies to the top-level repo.
> This can lead to unexpected bandwidth and disk usage for projects which include large submodules.
>
> For example, a user might wish to make a partial clone of Gerrit and would run: [`git clone --recurse-submodules  --filter=blob:5k https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L277)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt))</sup>.
>
> However, only the superproject would be a partial clone; all the submodules would have all blobs downloaded regardless of their size.
> With this change, the same filter can also be applied to submodules, meaning the expected bandwidth and disk savings apply consistently.
>
> To avoid changing default behavior, add a new clone flag, `--also-filter-submodules`.
> When this is set along with `--filter` and `--recurse-submodules`, the filter spec is passed along to [`git-submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/git-submodule.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule))</sup> and `git-submodule--helper`, such that submodule clones also have the filter applied.
>
> This applies the same filter to the superproject and all submodules.
> Users who need to customize the filter per-submodule would need to clone with `--no-recurse-submodules` and then manually initialize each submodule with the proper filter.
>
> Applying filters to submodules should be safe thanks to Jonathan Tan's recent work `[a, b, c]` eliminating the use of alternates as a method of accessing submodule objects, so any submodule object access now triggers a lazy fetch from the submodule's promisor remote if the accessed object is missing.
> This patch is a reworked version of `[d]`, which was created prior to Jonathan Tan's work.
>
> - `[a]`: [8721e2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8721e2eaedd0290ef399f638912a49b36402e715) ("Merge branch 'jt/partial-clone-submodule-1'", 2021-07-16, Git v2.33.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8721e2eaedd0290ef399f638912a49b36402e715) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daab8a564f8bbac55f70f8bf86c070e001a9b006))
> - `[b]`: [11e5d0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11e5d0a262c9ba664b7203a279513385bf055745) (Merge branch 'jt/grep-wo-submodule-odb-as-alternate', 2021-09-20, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11e5d0a262c9ba664b7203a279513385bf055745)) (Merge branch 'jt/grep-wo-submodule-odb-as-alternate', 2021-09-20)
> - `[c]`: [162a13b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/162a13b855ee8d920a31d6d1e928cef0f0a18e18) (Merge branch 'jt/no-abuse-alternate-odb-for-submodules', 2021-10-25, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/162a13b855ee8d920a31d6d1e928cef0f0a18e18) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9)) (Merge branch 'jt/no-abuse-alternate-odb-for-submodules', 2021-10-25)
> - `[d]`: https://lore.kernel.org/git/52bf9d45b8e2b72ff32aa773f2415bf7b2b86da2.1563322192.git.steadmon@google.com/

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/config/clone.txt#L9-L13):

> ### `clone.filterSubmodules`
>
> If a partial clone filter is provided (see `--filter` in
> [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)) and `--recurse-submodules` is used, also apply
> the filter to submodules.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L19):

> `[--filter=<filter> [--also-filter-submodules]] [--] <repository>`

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L185-L189):

> ### `--also-filter-submodules`
>
> Also apply the partial clone filter to any submodules in the repository.
> Requires `--filter` and `--recurse-submodules`.
> This can be turned on by
> default by setting the `clone.filterSubmodules` config option.

`git submodule` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f05da2b48b48a46db65fc768b3ffecaf996dd655/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L180-L183):

> If `--filter <filter spec>` is specified, the given partial clone filter will be
> applied to the submodule.
>
> See [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) for details on filter
> specifications.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), "[`git remote -v`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2785b71ef94799150d5ee02a24e6bbe330cae572/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L35)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt--v))</sup> now shows the `list-objects-filter` used during fetching from the remote, if available.

See [commit ef6d15c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef6d15ca536a50d916f8d9c7f600d650810161b1) (09 May 2022) by [Abhradeep Chakraborty (`Abhra303`)](https://github.com/Abhra303).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2785b71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2785b71ef94799150d5ee02a24e6bbe330cae572), 26 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef6d15ca536a50d916f8d9c7f600d650810161b1): teach `-v` to list filters for **promisor remotes**

> [`git remote -v`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef6d15ca536a50d916f8d9c7f600d650810161b1/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L35)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt--v))</sup> (`--verbose`) lists down the names of remotes along with their URLs.
> It would be beneficial for users to also specify the filter types for promisor remotes.
> Something like this -
>
> ```
> origin    remote-url (fetch) [blob:none]
> origin    remote-url (push)
> ```
>
> Teach `git remote -v` to also specify the filters for promisor remotes.
>
> Closes: https://github.com/gitgitgadget/git/issues/1211 Signed-off-by: Abhradeep Chakraborty chakrabortyabhradeep79@gmail.com Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano gitster@pobox.com

`git remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef6d15ca536a50d916f8d9c7f600d650810161b1/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L38-L39):

> For promisor remotes, also show which filter (`blob:none` etc.)
> are configured.

Examples:

```bash
git clone --filter=blob:none "file://$(pwd)/srv.bare"
git remote -v
    srv.bare (fetch) [blob:none]

git -C pc config remote.origin.partialCloneFilter object:type=commit
git -C pc remote -v
    srv.bare (fetch) [object:type=commit]
```