# How to modify the Git clone function

Tags: git, github, jgit

Since my work needs, I need to download only the commit object in `./git/objects` from the remote git repository. `/.git/` metadata contains some useful information. But in the pack file include the commit/tree/blob object. the tree/blob objects are too large, so the tree/blob object Should not be  download. Maybe I need to rebuild the git client or write a python script.

I saw some projects (like `https://github.com/lijiejie/GitHack`).It downloading the files step by step by parsing the `index` file, and finaly the commit/tree/blob objects are separated after the download.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjEIr.png)

But this method need to access the `.git` folder via HTTP, and you can't download the index file directly from github.

I don't understand how github communicates with the git client.

I tried to look at the underlying source code for C(https://github.com/git/git) and Java(https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), but the complicated structure puzzled me.

Is there any way to implement the function of downloading only the commit object? Or how can I help myself find the key code in the underlying source code.

If you know how to do this, please let me know. thank you very much.

PS: I need to download somefile of `.git` from github/gitlab(public Repositories) . But `--filter=blob:none` in github recive `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring`. And github's api have strong  limits.

Comment: any use of so called 'commit object'?

Comment: commit contains commit information. such as: `git cat-file -p 171a2e1` . this command can show the information in commit object.

Comment: you setup a webserver and it can run git commands locally(on the git server), so your client can get the logs, no need download anything. isn't that more lightweight?

Comment: thanks for your suggest. but I need to do some analysis work in github/gitlab. So, it needs in public net and Fast enough.

Comment: The complete clone time is too long when I have to process the information on the whole network. And github's api will limit the number of visits.

Comment: FWIW, Github uses [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) to interface with Git repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the git clone --filter option's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917616/what-is-the-git-clone-filter-options-syntax)

Comment: `git clone --filter=blob:none`

Comment: When i try to execute the command: `git clone --no-checkout --filter=blob:none "https://github.com/vulhub/vulhub.git" pc2`. It show me that `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring`

Comment: Unfortunately, github does not support the --filter feature. For more information :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195590/do-github-and-gitlab-support-git-clones-filter-parameter