# Do GitHub and GitLab support git clone's --filter parameter?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, jgit, rugged

I want to use git's `partialClone` feature. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917616/what-is-the-git-clone-filter-options-syntax) I saw the `git clone --filter=tree:none <repo>` command.

But when trying to execute on github, the prompt `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring`. It did not work.

I want to know if it is not supported by the GitHub website, or if there is a problem with my settings.

I asked the feedback staff of GitHub and have not got the answer from the technician.

Comment: Concrete example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This almost certainly isn't supported by GitHub or GitLab yet.

The `--filter` option is under active development and isn't really ready for general-purpose consumption yet. GitHub's [blog post about the release of Git 2.19 in September, 2018 says](https://github.blog/2018-09-10-highlights-from-git-2-19/)

> Note that most public servers do not yet support the feature, but you can play with `git clone --filter=blob:none` against your local Git 2.19 install.

Once this feature becomes more fully-developed and hosts start to support it I'm sure they won't do so quietly. As far as I know, no major cloud provider has made such an announcement yet.

**Update from OP 2019-03-21:**

> Not long ago, I received an official reply from github. They think that the `--filter` parameter is still an immature feature and is accompanied by some security issues. Therefore, this feature will not be supported in the short term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not long ago, I received an official reply from github. They think that the --filter parameter is still an immature feature and is accompanied by some security issues. Therefore, this feature will not be supported in the short term. 
I will continue to wait and will update this issue when the official support for this feature.

Comment: @Ph0rse, thanks for the update. I've incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is supported by [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#exclude-large-files-using-partial-clone)

> ### Exclude large files using Partial Clone
>
> Storing large binary files in Git is normally discouraged, because every large file added will be downloaded by everyone who clones or fetches changes thereafter.
>   This is slow, if not a complete obstruction when working from a slow or unreliable internet connection.
>
> **In GitLab 13.0, Partial Clone has been enabled for blob size filters, as well as experimentally for other filters.**
>
> This allows troublesome large files to be excluded from clones and fetches. When Git encounters a missing file, it will be downloaded on demand.
>
> When cloning a project, use the `--filter=blob:none` or `--filer=blob:limit=1m` to exclude blobs completely or by file size.
>   Note, Partial Clone requires at least Git 2.22.0.

(see also "[What is the `git clone --filter` option's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)")

> Read more in our recent blog, "[How Git Partial Clone lets you fetch only the large file you need](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/03/13/partial-clone-for-massive-repositories/)", from  **[James Ramsay](https://gitlab.com/jramsay)**.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/issues/2553).

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find an official blog post or news regarding the support, **GitHub does indeed appear to be rolling out `--filter` support**.

```
$ git clone --bare --single-branch --depth=1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux
```

Resulted in downloading 195.82MiB worth of around 74k objects.

```
$ git clone --bare --single-branch --depth=1 --filter=blob:none https://github.com/torvalds/linux
```

Resulted in downloading 2.15MiB worth of around 4.7k objects. That's 91x less data if all you want to do is know what files are in a repo.

Since you mention in `tree:none` I tested that too. Now it results in `fatal: expected 'tree:<depth>'` and my following experimentation shows that only `tree:0` works, which results in downloading  603bytes or so in a bare repo. If you try to clone and checkout then git will slowly figure out the objects it needs and clone the whole repo. Numbers higher than 0 result in: `fatal: remote error: filter 'tree' not supported (maximum depth: 0, but got: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding partial clone/spare checkout support in GitLab:

As of GitLab 12.4 (released 2019-10-22) partial cloning has been added as an optional alpha feature for self hosted instances. You can enable it instance wide via the feature flags api:

```
curl --data "value=true" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/features/gitaly_upload_pack_filter
```

You can get more information about this here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html

Just to be clear: **You cannot use this feature with gitlab.com hosted repositories at the time of last edit of this answer.**