# Setting up git-LFS remotely

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, large-file-upload

My co-worker just left his position, before he left, he created a repo with a lot of binary data(10GB of Unix Executable File) to our team GitLab without using git-LFS. When I try to clone the repo, it takes forever to clone. I researched a bit on setting up git-LFS, most articles show me how to set up LFS locally after cloning the repo. Is there a way to set up git-LFS remotely before cloning?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to convert anything you can use [Git's native filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964488/1290731), since GitLab now supports it and the repo's already got the history so might as well keep it. Web UI's can be made to support anything the command line does, but unless you see a "git lfs migrate" option on GitLab somewhere no one's taught it to do that yet so to do a full conversion you'll have to fetch, lfs migrate, push -f.