# Track a subdirectory of a remote git repository

Tags: git

Suppose there is an online repository with url `https://website.domain/repo.git` and its structure is something like this.

```
repo/
|
|--a/
|  |
|  |--aa/
|  |
|  |--ab/
|
|--b/
```

I only work with the sub-directory `aa` and have nothing to do with the rest of the repository. So I only need to track `aa` (The whole repository is pretty big). Now, I don't have any authority over this online repository, otherwise I would've simply turned `aa` into a submodule.

In short, how do I set `repo/a/aa` as origin instead of the whole `repo` so that I can pull any changes to `repo/a/aa`?

Comment: Nop, no way. In such situation I'd clone the entire `repo.git`, extract the subdirectory into a separate repo using `git subtree` and import the new repo into you project using `git submodule` or `git subtree`. Later when you get know the upstream repo is updated you update your local clone, update the extracted subdirectory using the same `git subtree` and update your project. That's the simplest way I could imagine.

Comment: @phd, that's what I am doing at the moment. You probably already know this, but git, like any agile software being developed everyday doesn't always have documentation which is as up to date as the software itself. For example, some git sub-command which was implemented recently may not have been documented yet. This question is directed towards someone who is more acquainted than I am with the inner development of git (a contributor/maintainer for example), so that I can find out about a tool like that.

Comment: Also like I said, the whole repository is pretty big (a couple of gigs as opposed to a few MB which I am working with) and I don't have a good bandwidth at my region. Otherwise, I wouldn't have bothered with looking for something like this.

Comment: You only need good bandwidth for the 1st clone. Updates are usually small and cheap.

Comment: @phd, my work environment is in a live image, that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't—not yet, anyway.

That's not 100% right: there is a bunch of experimental stuff using *promisor packs* and *filter expressions*.  The documentation that does exist for this is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone/2.19.0); there is more information about all of this in [What is the git clone --filter option's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917616/1256452)

None of this stuff is ready for anyone to *use*.  You should feel free to *experiment* with it, but if you get something working in Git 2.2x, it might stop working in the next version of Git.  This isn't like `git switch` and `git restore`, which are still marked experimental, but are pretty well defined and not likely to break tomorrow.  This is stuff with known limitations, bugs, incompatibilities between specific Git revisions, and code that's just not really *there* yet.

(Side note: beware of the verb *track*, which already has about 3 or 4 meanings in Git, none of them compatible with each other, nor with what I think you mean by your word *track* here.)