# How to filter large files on git pull?

Tags: git, file, filter

There is a git repo that I wanted to clone, but it has many large files in it that I am not interested in. I looked at "sparse checkout" to get only one folder, but that still downloads many gigabytes so it's pointless.

I tried cloning using the `--filter` option - my first attempt again downloaded the whole thing but adding `--no-checkout` downloaded much less:

```
git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout --filter=blob:limit=2m
```

But there were no files in the repo (besides the `.git` folder which was now a more manageable 1GB).

So how do I get the files, without the large ones? Doing `git checkout master` gets the full repo again. Adding the filter to that command gives me an "unknown option" error. Same for `git pull` with the filter.

Answer (score 0):

> But there were no files in the repo

Yes, there are. There are no files visible in the working tree, but that doesn't matter. It is not the repo.

> (besides the .git folder which was now a more manageable 1GB).

Yup. And that's the repo. And that's where the files are.

If you want to *see* the files, you need to check them out of the repo.

> Doing git checkout master gets the full repo again.

Not the *full* repo. It gets just the filtered master branch. So it will not be "many gigabytes". But yes, it will take up more space because the files in the repo are being copied into the work tree.

If you still want to make the repo smaller you could now run `filter-branch` or `filter-repo`.

Comment: It's possible that the filtered-away objects are *in* the tip commit of the master branch. If this is the case, `git checkout master` will fulfill the promises by obtaining the large objects. This is where adding sparse checkout can be helpful: you can avoid checking out specific large files.

Comment: "It gets just the filtered master branch" - no that's not correct. It gave me every file in the repo including all the ones over 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit of background to [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65092862/1256452), I'll note that this:

> ```
> git clone --depth=1 --no-checkout --filter=blob:limit=2m
> ```

uses a new feature that's still in development to produce what Git calls a *partial clone* with a *promisor remote* and *promisor pack*.  There are many details [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt).  The feature is still experimental, so some details might change somewhat in the future.

If you are using this feature, *read and understand* the *entire* technical documentation I linked, which describes existing limitations of partial clones and some of the plans to fix them in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I've read through that page. I got the gist but I'm not sure I fully understand it... and it doesn't seem to answer my question at all. git checkout still downloads and checks out every single file over 2MB.

Comment: If you've gotten a promisor pack, `git checkout` is *meant* to only download those objects that will actually be accessed, so if you set up your sparse checkout ahead of time and then execute the sparse checkout, it's only *supposed* to download those objects that are required. This feature is not yet ready for general use though, and it's possible that this "only download what will be checked out" code has bugs in it. You're working right on the bleeding-edge here, so you might consider cloning the Git source and debugging it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To complement [`git clone --filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt) (that I [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)), you also have, with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git fetch --refetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f5e8851737282c9dd342032fe9a2d8b10367c9a/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L167)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---refetch))</sup> learned to fetch everything without telling the other side what we already have, which is useful when you cannot trust what you have in the local object store.

See [commit 4963d3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4963d3e41fa454500760fe6f8fb1bab890c1c3eb), [commit 7390f05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7390f05a3c674e354ba2f52632046fa0a5c3e501), [commit 011b775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/011b7757279e52043a0398b0a3b1d497d8417daf), [commit 3c7bab0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c7bab06e12922fbcb375187eb60ac426fc72a3a), [commit 869a0eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/869a0eb4ebddad9ea758464526524ed06f5a13a9), [commit 4dfd092](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dfd0925cbba78cc737e3af29faa5774bbc7b6a3), [commit 1836836](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1836836593e90b515269b564b384dcf091a4493d) (28 Mar 2022) by [Robert Coup (`rcoup`)](https://github.com/rcoup).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0f5e885](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f5e8851737282c9dd342032fe9a2d8b10367c9a), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c7bab06e12922fbcb375187eb60ac426fc72a3a): add `--refetch` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Robert Coup</sup>

> Teach fetch and transports the `--refetch` option to force a full fetch without negotiating common commits with the remote.
>
> **Use when applying a new partial clone filter to refetch all matching objects.**

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3c7bab06e12922fbcb375187eb60ac426fc72a3a/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L166-L174):

> ifndef::git-pull[]
>
> ### `--refetch`
>
> Instead of negotiating with the server to avoid transferring commits and
> associated objects that are already present locally, this option fetches
> all objects as a fresh clone would.
>
> Use this to reapply a partial clone
> filter from configuration or using `--filter=` when the filter
> definition has changed.