# Does libgit2 support --filter=blob:none

Tags: git, rust, libgit2

Is there a way to only read the history without the files in libgit2? e.g. something like git --filter=blob:none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see that option for [`git clone --filter=blob:none`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt), documented in Git 2.27, as I documented it in "[What is the `git clone --filter` option's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)".

But I don't see [any equivalent feature in libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/search?q=%22clone%22%20%22filter%22&type=issues), only a [`git_blob_filter_options`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/search?q=git_blob_filter_options), which is not used for cloning.

On a related topic, there is a PR pending for [supporting sparse checkout](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/5833).

So nothing yet regarding partial clone (for which there is an [opened feature request (5564)](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/5564) as well).

Comment: Thank you for that answer, then I'd execute 'git' for now and capture the results.