# git - only fetch the files, not the history

Tags: performance, git, repository

when I am running `git pull` or `git fetch`, I obviously retrieve both history and files. For huge projects, that takes very much time. I wonder how this process could be sped up, as for some projects I am only interested in the source code and not in the history. Is there a way to tell git that I only want to fetch the current snapshot of the files and not the whole history as well?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible. Actually it's not what version control is all about.

Comment: Git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014) will be much more efficient with shallow cloning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217326/6309

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably want to look at the `--depth` option in `git clone`--called a "shallow clone".  In particular, you probably want:

```
git clone --depth=1 <url>
```

If the project is on GitHub, you can always use the download links from there.  Note, there are some catches to using a shallow clone:

> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

But that sounds like something you can live with.

Also, as positron pointed out, you can do this with `git archive` as well.

Comment: @jszameister Git simply doesn't support the concept? I think you've misunderstood.

Comment: I completely forgot about the remote option to `git-archive`!

Answer (score 5):

If there is a webview like gitweb or cgit, you can very well take a snapshot. But I don't think fetch of the code alone is *possible*. Because fetch is working on your git objects and not the code.

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=gitolite@server:repo.git HEAD | bzip2 > repo-snapshot.tar.bz2
```

Comment: That sounds good, however it looks like it's not supported by github. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *shallow clone*:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://url/of/repo
```

However you won't be able to commit/push changes made in a shallow clone.