# How to fetch enough commits to do a merge in a shallow clone

Tags: git, merge, shallow-clone

What I'm trying to do: test pull requests from github. I want to locally merge a pull request into master and run some tests on the result. Since the repository is huge, I do a shallow clone.

To be able to do the merge, I fetch more and more commits (`git fetch` with increasing `--depth`) until I have the `merge-commit` between master the pull request.

However, it doesn't work every time. It looks like I do not only need the merge-base, but also every commit in the `master..merge`_base range. I'm not sure however how to do that.

So, the question is: how do I fetch enough history to do the merge?

Answer (score 19):

If you have the history from when `feature` branched from `master` but don't want the full history of master then you can estimate a branching date and use;

```
git fetch --shallow-since=<date> origin master
```

It's hard to use any other form of `git fetch` to do what you want (query the remote for the merge-base) because `git fetch` fetches refs. There might not be a ref that you're looking for.

You can automate the digging using the following script.

```
while [ -z $( git merge-base master feature ) ]; do     
    git fetch -q --deepen=1 origin master feature;
done
```

Comment: Doing so many fetches only one level deeper seems awfully inefficient because of network and git packing overhead. Maybe rather use something like `deepen=100`.

Comment: @fabb completely agree. Tune as desired.

Comment: The second command just infinite loops when I try it

```
usage: git merge-base [-a | --all] <commit> <commit>...
   or: git merge-base [-a | --all] --octopus <commit>...
   or: git merge-base --independent <commit>...
   or: git merge-base --is-ancestor <commit> <commit>
   or: git merge-base --fork-point <ref> [<commit>]

    -a, --all             output all common ancestors
    --octopus             find ancestors for a single n-way merge
    --independent         list revs not reachable from others
   <more but character limits>
```

Comment: Note that [`--deepen` requires Git 2.11+ (from 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997175/1026).

Comment: The `git fetch --since` doesn't seem to work reliably with merged Git history. It seems to often fetch the wrong branch of history and then you don't have the commit you requested.

Answer (score 5):

I recently hit this issue and found a way that saved a ton of time, get the [merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) commit from the API rather than get enough repo information downloaded to calculate it https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits

This api call amounts to

```
gh api \
  repos/my_github_user/my_repo/compare/main...my_pr_branch \
  | jq -r '.merge_base_commit.sha'"
```

Or curl if you prefer

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/my_user/my_repo/compare/main...my_pr_branch
```

here's more of what my github workflow / action looks like

```
      - name: Fetch merge base SHA from API
        run: |
          my_merge_base_cmd="gh api repos/github/github/compare/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}...${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} | jq -r '.merge_base_commit.sha'"
          echo $my_merge_base_cmd
          my_merge_base=$(eval $my_merge_base_cmd)
          echo "MY_MERGE_BASE_SHA=$my_merge_base" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Fetch merge base SHA
        run: |
          echo $MY_MERGE_BASE_SHA
          git fetch \
            --no-tags \
            --prune \
            --progress \
            --no-recurse-submodules \
            --depth=1 \
            origin $MY_MERGE_BASE_SHA

      - name: Checkout merge base SHA
        run: |
          echo $MY_MERGE_BASE_SHA
          git checkout \
            --force \
            $MY_MERGE_BASE_SHA
```

Basically once I have the merge base SHA checked out I can build artifacts and compare them artifacts I built on the PR branch

If you need the commits *between* the merge-base and the PR, you'd have to shallow fetch them too, but at least using the merge base you know your ending point

Note, best to use the `sha`, not the `ref` for the API call to fetch merge base, as the `ref` can change what it points to (someone merging main into their PR branch for example), resulting in a race condition.

Comment: If you are using **GitLab**, you get the merge base commit SHA in either `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA` or (if mirroring an external repo such as GitHub) in `$CI_EXTERNAL_PULL_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA`. You can then fetch this commit, again using depth 1.

Comment: "If you need the commits between the merge-base and the PR, you'd have to shallow fetch them too" - you may be able to avoid this using `git replace`. For example if you want to use `nx affected...` to determine changed packages, it is enough to (1) use `git replace --graft <headSHA> <baseSHA>` to create a new temporary commit with the contents of headSHA but with baseSHA as its parent; (2) use `newHeadSHA=$(cat .git/refs/replace/<headSHA>)` to get the SHA of the new commit; (3) use `nx affected --base=<baseSHA> --head=<newHeadSHA>` to get changes.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39880 as to why you can't rely on `github.event.pull_request.base.sha` here. :-/

Answer (score 3):

What you need (I think), in a catch-22 way, is 'git describe --all --first-parent' to tell you the depth of the given commit from the appropriate branch. However I'm not sure how to get that from Github before you do your shallow fetch ;-)

Comment: Even in that case, the depth of a commit is computed using the shortest path from the master to the commit, but I (seem to) need all the commit between master and the merge_base, which may be deeper than merge_base.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't thought of the full traversal to the merge_base (rather than the shortest path). If you have a merge loop that had lots of small commits that depth could be quite large. Unfortunately the shallow fetch is only limited by a counted depth, rather than any other scheme. And I'm still not sure how to determine the depth anyway!