# Reverse git depth=1

Tags: git

I cloned a directory with `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/`.

I saw that the repo was updated on github, Now I'd like to `pull` to latest. I `git pull`, but nothing happened.

On another question in SO, I saw there's no way to do this prior to 2.x.x, but no mention how to after that version. I am on `git version 2.7.2.windows.1`.

How can I checkout the latest commit, without cloning from scratch?

Comment: Related: [How to git fetch efficiently from a shallow clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352894/how-to-git-fetch-efficiently-from-a-shallow-clone) (but mind the age of some of the answers)

Comment: @poke that answer only talk about `git clone` paired with `--depth`, nothing about changing the depth afterwards, but thanks.

Comment: Can you check if the issue persists with git 2.9.2? https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: @VonC Yes, it does. "Current branch mastesr is up to date."

Answer (score 0):

> I git pull, but nothing happened.

That should mean no new commit is to be pulled from the remote repo.

You can check that with `git ls-remote` and compare its output with `git log -1`

Comment: The repo was updated, I am definitely not on the latest commit :)

Comment: @AgafadaEm then what does a `git fetch origin master:master --depth 1` returns?

Comment: "fatal: refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository"

Comment: @AgafadaEm your remote repo is not a bare repo?

Comment: No. I `git clone`ed, it's doesn't do bare repos.

Comment: @AgafadaEm git clone can clone a remote repo which is bare or not bare (into a local repo). Is your remote repo bare or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120668/discussion-between-agafada-em-and-vonc).