# Git find modified files since <ref> from a shallow clone

Tags: git, git-diff, git-remote, git-fetch

I'm on a CI box running tests. To speed it up, I'm just doing a shallow clone:

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:JoshCheek/some_repo.git
```

Assuming all the tests pass, I want to trigger the next step in the pipeline. What to trigger is based on which files changed between the last **d**eployment (ref `d123456`) and the **c**urrent ref I just tested (ref `c123456`). If I had done a normal clone, I could find out like this this:

```
git diff --name-only d123456 c123456
```

But my clone is shallow, so it doesn't know about those commits. I see that I can use `git fetch --depth=n` to get more of the history, but I only know the SHA, not the depth of the SHA. Here's a set of ways that could presumably answer this question:

```
# hypothetical remote diff
git diff --name-only origin/d123456 origin/c123456

# hypothetical ref based fetch
git fetch --shallow-through d123456
git diff --name-only d123456 c123456

# hypothetical way to find the depth I need
depth=`git remote depth-to d123456`
git fetch --depth "$depth"
git diff --name-only d123456 c123456
```

Otherwise it seems like I might have to write a loop and keep invoking `--deepen` until my history contains the commit. That seems painful (meaning annoying to write / maintain) and expensive (meaning slow, remember that the purpose of the shallow clone is to reduce this cost).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Otherwise it seems like I might have to write a loop and keep invoking `--deepen` until my history contains the commit. That seems painful ...

It *is* painful (and slow, as you note a bit later).

Modern Git (since version 2.11) does have a new `git fetch` option:

> --shallow-exclude=<revision>
>
>   Deepen or shorten the history of a shallow repository to
>      exclude commits reachable from a specified remote branch or tag.
>      This option can be specified multiple times.

I have not tried this; it's not clear if it allows a hash ID (the tests use names) and in any case you would specify the *parent(s)* of the commit you want to deepen through, rather than the commit you want to *obtain*.  But it might suffice.

(I really think a better method is to keep reference clones you can borrow-from.)

Comment: Oh, nice catch, I totally missed that! Sadly, it seems Github doesn't support it, when I try it says `fatal: Server does not support --shallow-exclude` :(

Comment: Can you go into more detail on that last note? It's not clear to me what a reference clone is (are you saying a fully cloned repo that is cached on the CI server?).

Comment: Yes: with a reference clone, you run `git clone --reference <path> [options] <url>` and Git calls up the other Git at the URL as usual, but then borrows or copies (see `--dissociate`) the objects from the reference clone rather than copying them across the network. Measured on a real project, I trimmed the clone wall-clock time from nearly two hours to just a few minutes by using reference clones. (This involved a number of fairly large repositories.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try keeping a cached clone, so far it's looking promising.

Comment: 2021 update: Github supports shallow-exclude now, but you can't use a commit hash as an argument (you get the error "the remote end hung up unexpectedly" if you try)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions to reduce the clone time and space besides shallow-clone.

1.`git clone <url> -b <branch> --single-branch`

This fetches only the data reachable by `<branch>`. Not so effective as `--depth=1` but still better than a full clone. It works fine when the repo has many diverged branches.

2.`git init;git fetch <url> <tag>`

Similarily it fetches only the data reachable by `<tag>`.

3.Create and use a mirror repo.

`git clone <url> --mirror -- /foo/mirror`. `/foo/mirror` is the mirror repo. Suppose your CI system starts multiple instances simultaneously. Clone each via `git clone <url> --reference=/foo/mirror -- <instanceN>`. In each clone, only the data that can not be found in the mirror repo will be downloaded from the remote repo. You could delete instances to save the space when a job is done. But just keep and update the mirror repo by `git fetch` regularly based on the update frequency of the remote repo. Once a day in the mid-night, or once a week on Sunday for example.

4.Use `git worktree`.

Make a clone, keep it and update it first when each CI instance starts. Use `git worktree` to checkout revisions into different working trees for each instance.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I'm ultimately going with a cached clone. Might need to use some of the ideas from the others here, if its state gets wonky, but I'm hopeful for now.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and used this

`git clone --shallow-since=<date>`

I had to store not only the SHA of my last deployment but the date of my last deployment, but otherwise worked great.