# Can I issue "git remote update" to download partial of the remote git

Tags: git, github

I have very slow access to some gits. So it is quite likely the simple "git remote update“ will fail with something like:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
error: Could not fetch origin
```

Do I have a way to update only 10% of the remote git? In this way, I hope I can incremently get the whole  git updated finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a shallow clone:

```
git clone --depth=1 <url>
```

Then, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217326/6309), you can fetch only:

- [since a date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39994584/6309): `--shallow-since=<date>`
- [up to a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794129/6309): `--shallow-exclude=<branch|tag>`
- [with a greater depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997175/6309): `--deepen=N`

In each instance, that would avoid dealing with the *full* history of the repository over a slow network.

Comment: @AlicePurcell Thank you. I have restored the proper link.

Comment: Probably worth describing this as "up to a branch/tag" as shallow-exclude doesn't seem to accept commit hashes

Comment: @AlicePurcell https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---shallow-excludeltrevisiongt says it accepts "revision". A branch or tag is a revision, but so is a commit (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_revision).

Comment: (a) it goes on to say "to exclude commits reachable from a specified remote branch or tag", quite specifically. (b) it definitely didn't work when I tried it ("server hung up unexpectedly"). However, if you get it working, I'd be overjoyed to be wrong :)

Comment: @AlicePurcell Strange. What version of Git are you using? I am not able to test it at the moment. A `git clone --shallow-exclude=8d884aeda07e56560044e95fd8bfdf5819b2796b https://github.com/VonC/gpr gpr2` returns `fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'`. It is true the tests are only using tag, not commits: https://github.com/git/git/blob/e6362826a0409539642a5738db61827e5978e2e4/t/t5539-fetch-http-shallow.sh#L109-L129

Comment: The laptop I tried it on suffered permanent disk death on Friday so I can't check the git version any more :( I was using a git: rather than https: URL so maybe that explains the different failure mode. I definitely got it working passing in a branch to shallow-exclude — but only if the branch was in the direct history of the branch I was fetching. If they only shared a common ancestor, I got the unexpected hang-up error again.

Comment: @AlicePurcell Darn... this command is *much* more dangerous than I thought...