# Error: GitHub can’t show files that are this big right now - but the file is only 1.06 MB

Tags: git, github, terminal

I uploaded an HTML file to a GitHub repository two different ways: drag and drop and add/commit/push using Git on Terminal. In both cases I received the error that the file is too big to display, yet it is only 1.06 MB. I've searched the documentation on GitHub and here on SO. Any thoughts please?

[image]

Comment: And that's too big. What kind of "thoughts" do you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems expected: GitHub will not show the content (or a diff) of a file larger than a certain size (over 1MB).

See [nodejs/node issue 5533](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5533) and [nodejs/node PR 6337](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6337) as an example.

How that file was added (drag and drop or regular push) will not change what is a server-side policy.

---

If, later on, one would need to see that file, you can:

- either [extract it from the latest archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776113/6309) using [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive);
- a [filtered clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49917616/6309) (`git clone --filter`);
- use a `sparse checkout` as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/6309);
- use a [shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217326/6309) in order to limit the history (and size) of what you are importing;
- *combine* both a [shallow and sparse clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526704/6309);

Most of those advises derive from the work/articles done by [Derrick Stolee](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/59/derrick-stolee) from Microsoft:

- "[Bring your monorepo down to size with sparse-checkout](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/) " (Jan. 2020)
- "[Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/) " (Dec. 2020)

> - In a partial clone, some data is not served immediately and is delayed until the client needs it.
> - Blobless clones skip blobs except those needed at checkout time.
> - Treeless clones skip all trees in the history in favor of downloading a full copy of the trees needed for each checkout.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/data-ratio-blobless.png]

So if cloning the repo is what you need in order to see those files... you have options to do so in an economical way, without downloading too much.