# Issues when uploading audio file into Github

Tags: html, css, github, audio, mp3

I have create an html file in VS Code which included a mp3 file and and the audio run all well whedn I try opening it in may browser. However, when I uploaded the folder into Github in order to get the url link through the Github Pages, the audio .mp3 file was said to be too big. '(*Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.*)'
Any ideas to solve this issue? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054280/128761

Comment: Thank you very much! My mp3 file is 6.3 MB. Will I have to choose another file or are there any ways to make it less heavy? Thank you

Comment: I have cut my mp3 file to less than 1 MB but it still didn't work. Maybe it is not because the file is too big

Comment: I never have this problem before and never use LFS before, I'm not sure that [Git LFS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) can help or not.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers, vee! But it seems not because of the file too big. One of my friends solve it but it still not work on my own laptop.