# git clone in version 1.9/2 no longer creates remote tracking branches for all branches in my repo

Tags: git, capistrano

According to the git documentation, [git clone creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). However, today I was setting up a new machine image on Ubuntu 14.04, and in the process upgraded my git from 1.7.9.5 to 2.0.2. When I was attempting to use capistrano to deploy code from a different (non-master) branch to the box, it was failing, and I tracked down the root cause to the issue that `git clone --depth 1` (the command that cap generated and uses) was not creating remote tracking branches for each branch. As a result, attempting to reference a checkin from said non-master branch failed. I did a

```
  git branch -r
```

And saw that only

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Were shown, not all of my other branches too.

I see that there were some [behavior changes introduced in git 1.9](https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/06/better-support-for-shallow-clones-in-git-1-9/), also [referenced on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-git-clone-depth-1-shallow-clone-more-useful-than-it-makes-out).

Can someone explain why this change causes the behavior I am now seeing, and what the command is that I would need to now execute to get this working as it did under git 1.7?

Thanks!

Comment: check `git config remote.origin.fetch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc for [git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> **--[no-]single-branch**
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the
>   `--branch` option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at.
>
> ***When creating a shallow clone with the `--depth`option, this is the default, unless `--no-single-branch` is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches.***

Not knowing much about capistrano, are you able to get it to clone with the `--no-single-branch` option or omit the shallow clone `--depth` option? or get it to clone the desired branch only using the `--branch` option?

As you were on 1.7.9.5 previously, you did not see this behaviour since it was [1.7.10 that introduced the single-branch option to git clone](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt)

Comment: Based on your reply, I just removed this line item from my capistrano script and now it's working: set :git_shallow_clone, 1