# shallow updated not allowed

Tags: git, github

I have:

- **Repo A** - *a templated set of files which represent a good starting point for new repos*
- **Repo B** - *an "instantiated" version of Repo A which I have built and now want to commit to as it's own repo*

I am very new to the "shallow clone" process but had read that using it was a good way to achieve the results above ([article](http://kevinthompson.info/blog/2013/11/11/using-git-repos-as-project-templates.html)). Now, however, I'm at the stage where it's time to make a commit to Repo B and when I try I get the error:

> [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)

It does let me commit locally but I'm at a complete loss how to *push* that back to github. :(

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: i have 1.9.5 (apple Git 50.3) on my system but I run my non CLI git with SourceTree from Atlassian which embeds a 2.2.1 version of git.

Comment: Ok, I was checking if it was >= 1.9, because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309.