# Freeing unnecessary Docker image's space

Tags: git, maven, docker

I have a maven project that I am building and running inside Docker container. My maven build needs to have an access to my project's GIT repository for some commit info extraction so I need to temporarily include my repository inside an image.

The problem is that my repository weights more than 600MB and it makes my image unnecessarily huge. I cannot add my repo to an image, perform some action and then remove it later. Well, I can. But it will not save any space due to nature of Docker images. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back to this one a few years later and now the above problem is solved by multi-stage builds.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider accessing the git repo through a [host volume mounted in your docker container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).

Or you could consider cloning only the part of the git repo you need (just one branch, only a [few commits as a shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309)). That would minimize the size of the git repo in the image.