# Multiple users for single repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit

This is my problem:

I have a single server used by multiple users though different logins. The limitation is disk size. 
Currently, separate directories are created and users have checked out the repo into their respective directories. But this is taking up most of the disk space.

I want to reduce the disk usage. If I use a single account then the commits will become messy. What is the best solution for multiple users to use git on the server?

How can I configure multiple users for a single repo? I can configure .gitconfigure for multiple users, but the .git/config contains a URL which contains the username.

Comment: How do you expect these people to be able to do work?

Comment: Let me modify my question. I am using Windows Server 2012

Comment: No, I mean, even if you solve the URL problem (trivial via ssh config), you're going to have multiple people trying to edit/build/test code in a single directory. How is that ever going to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a centralized repository approach, check [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow) for more details.

This way you will create a single `bare` repository that each developer will be able to access. And each of them will be able to clone and create their own private working copy on their local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you?
1. have a bare repo on server?
2. each user has a cloned repo(not bare, has working tree) on server too?

If all yes(everything on server), perhaps try "shallow" clone to save disk space:

[image]

---

Then, use patches work flow to manage your main repo:

You create one bare repo for shallow cloning, and one repo(not bare) for applying patches.

Others clone that bare repo with shallow, then coding, commit, create patches, send patches to you.

You apply those patches on feature branch, review the code, merge the branch into master branch, push master to bare repo.

---

push/fetch/pull can be used normally, please refer to [Is it safe to shallow clone with --depth 1, create commits, and pull updates again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga).