# Is it possible to work with git or something similar and not need to have the whole repository saved onto computer?

Tags: git, version-control, file-sharing

Looking for a way to file share with version control between a lot of people on the same network. We are looking at using git, but we are wondering if there is any way of not having to download and contain the whole repository on your computer. The files shared will include regular text files, but also binary files such as zipped folders and another type our company uses. I know git isn't the best with binary files as it needs some workarounds to properly diff binary files. Just asking for any tips on using git to satisfy the problems above and making it easy to learn for others, or if there are any other similar ways of achieving these goals. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

> if there is any way of not having to download and contain the whole repository on your computer

That can be interpreted as:

- not having the full history (**[git shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941889/6309)**)
- not having the full content ([git sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114887/6309))

So it is possible, but again, git is a source control system best to manage... sources.