# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to run repositary
[angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) after doing all installation.
When I run command `npm start` or `webpack` it throws following errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 10:0-24

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 11:0-26

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 12:0-25

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 13:0-24

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 14:0-26

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angularclass/hmr' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 16:0-28

ERROR in ./src/main.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angularclass/hmr' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts 7:12-40

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zone.js/dist/zone' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/polyfills.browser.ts 27:0-28

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/polyfills.browser.ts 35:4-49

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 18:0-32

ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 19:0-37

ERROR in ./src/app/environment.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/environment.ts 5:13-37
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 4:14-39
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 5:13-37
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 6:15-41
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angularclass/hmr' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 7:12-40
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.js 9:0-54
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts




ERROR in ./src/app/about/about.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\about'
 @ ./src/app/about/about.component.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/about/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/about/about.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\about'
 @ ./src/app/about/about.component.ts 3:15-41
 @ ./src/app/about/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home'
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/x-large/x-large.directive.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\x-large'
 @ ./src/app/home/x-large/x-large.directive.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/home/x-large/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/web_animations_driver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/web_animations_driver.js 8:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.js 13:0-70
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/dom_events.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/dom_events.js 13:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events.js 13:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.js 13:0-51
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'to-string-loader' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter'
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts 33:21-52
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\resource_loader'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.js 6:0-51
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform_providers.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\resource_loader'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.js 7:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform_providers.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/testability.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/testability.js 8:0-53
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/private_import_core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/private_import_core.js 8:0-54
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/animation_driver.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/html_sanitizer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/html_sanitizer.js 8:0-42
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/style_sanitizer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/style_sanitizer.js 8:0-42
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/url_sanitizer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/url_sanitizer.js 8:0-42
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\location'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.js 13:0-51
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\location'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.js 14:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/tools/common_tools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\tools'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/tools/common_tools.js 8:0-47
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/tools/tools.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter'
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts 35:22-54
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/+detail/detail.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\+detail'
 @ ./src/app/+detail/detail.component.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/+detail/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.routes.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/about/about.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json-loader' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter'
 @ ./src/app/about/about.component.ts 35:12-66
 @ ./src/app/about/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/web_animations_player.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/web_animations_player.js 8:0-43
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/web_animations_driver.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/src/platform-browser.js
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/title/title.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\title'
 @ ./src/app/home/title/title.service.ts 2:13-37
 @ ./src/app/home/title/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/home/title/title.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\title'
 @ ./src/app/home/title/title.service.ts 3:13-37
 @ ./src/app/home/title/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'hammerjs'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'protractor'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'selenium-webdriver'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'source-map'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'uglify-js'.

ERROR in [default] 
Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts:6:46 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts:10:63 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts:10:78 
Cannot find name 'PlatformRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\platform_providers.d.ts:2:66 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\resource_loader\resource_loader_impl.d.ts:9:48 
Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser.d.ts:3:58 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser.d.ts:14:56 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser.d.ts:14:71 
Cannot find name 'PlatformRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser.d.ts:16:40 
Cannot find name 'ErrorHandler'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\location\browser_platform_location.d.ts:14:53 
Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\location\browser_platform_location.d.ts:20:19 
Cannot find name 'LocationChangeListener'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\location\browser_platform_location.d.ts:21:21 
Cannot find name 'LocationChangeListener'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\testability.d.ts:9:54 
Cannot find name 'GetTestability'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\testability.d.ts:11:26 
Cannot find name 'TestabilityRegistry'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\testability.d.ts:12:36 
Cannot find name 'TestabilityRegistry'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\testability.d.ts:12:95 
Cannot find name 'Testability'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\tools\tools.d.ts:22:49 
Cannot find name 'ComponentRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\tools\tools.d.ts:22:67 
Cannot find name 'ComponentRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\animation_driver.d.ts:15:150 
Cannot find name 'AnimationPlayer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\by.d.ts:23:28 
Cannot find name 'DebugElement'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\by.d.ts:31:44 
Cannot find name 'DebugElement'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\by.d.ts:39:27 
Cannot find name 'Type'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\by.d.ts:39:49 
Cannot find name 'DebugElement'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\ng_probe.d.ts:14:60 
Cannot find name 'DebugNode'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\debug\ng_probe.d.ts:27:46 
Cannot find name 'Provider'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_adapter.d.ts:19:24 
Cannot find name 'Type'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:13:57 
Cannot find name 'RootRenderer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:20:36 
Cannot find name 'RenderComponentType'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:20:58 
Cannot find name 'Renderer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:25:44 
Cannot find name 'Renderer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:32:64 
Cannot find name 'RenderComponentType'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_tokens.d.ts:17:31 
Cannot find name 'OpaqueToken'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events\event_manager.d.ts:12:44 
Cannot find name 'OpaqueToken'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events\event_manager.d.ts:19:54 
Cannot find name 'NgZone'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events\event_manager.d.ts:22:15 
Cannot find name 'NgZone'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events\hammer_gestures.d.ts:16:44 
Cannot find name 'OpaqueToken'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\events\key_events.d.ts:21:86 
Cannot find name 'NgZone'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security\dom_sanitization_service.d.ts:83:54 
Cannot find name 'Sanitizer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security\dom_sanitization_service.d.ts:92:31 
Cannot find name 'SecurityContext'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security\dom_sanitization_service.d.ts:134:18 
Cannot find name 'SecurityContext'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\about\about.component.ts:31:28 
Cannot find name 'ActivatedRoute'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.component.ts:16:4 
Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.module.ts:58:29 
Cannot find name 'ApplicationRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.resolver.ts:7:37 
Cannot find name 'Resolve'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.resolver.ts:11:17 
Cannot find name 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.resolver.ts:11:48 
Cannot find name 'RouterStateSnapshot'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\app.routes.ts:9:21 
Cannot find name 'Routes'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\home.component.ts:17:12 
Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\home.component.ts:19:12 
Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\title\title.service.ts:7:27 
Cannot find name 'Http'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\x-large\x-large.directive.ts:10:23 
Cannot find name 'ElementRef'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\app\home\x-large\x-large.directive.ts:10:45 
Cannot find name 'Renderer'.

ERROR in [default] E:\mya4p\gtLbA4p\angular2-webpack-starter\src\polyfills.browser.ts:45:2 
Cannot find name 'require'.
```

My updated dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.15.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.29",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.9",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.15.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following steps as they explained it in the README file.

**Clone the repository**

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git
```

**Change directory into the project's root directory**

`cd angular2-webpack-starter`

**Install the repository with npm**

`npm install`

**Start the server**

`npm start`

Now open browser and type the url `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: thanks but why it didn't worked if i did:: git clone https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga