# Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node_modules\@ionic-native\camera\ngx'

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I am using ionic platform with Angular.

Seeing this error in `npm install`:

```
C:/Users/Lenovo/node_modules/@ionic-native/camera/ngx/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:\Users\Lenovo\node_modules\@ionic-native\camera\ngx'
```

Below is my AppModule import list:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { NgProgressModule } from 'ngx-progressbar';
```

Please let me know what i am missing here. Thanks

Comment: did you try running npm install or npm install @angular/core --save ?

Comment: ionic version  and angular version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189771/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-angular-core)

Comment: Format code, fix the language.

Answer (score 0):

Seams something is wrong with your plugins. [Try to add your camera plugin again.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera#installation)
Within the Terminal, change to directory of your project and execute this two commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
npm install @ionic-native/camera
```

Also make sure to add your injectable service to a provider.