# What is the minimum amount of source required to build android?

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

When one specifies:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

and then tries to sync with:

```
repo sync
```

Then git tries to download a huge amount of information which takes hours, and uses about 50GB of space.

But it seems that if one does:

```
repo sync -c
```

Then it will sync only the current branch - for example, if you specify the branch for marshmallow, it will download repositories only for that branch.

And lastly, if one specifies the "depth" to be 1, then it takes only the latest snapshot, so instead of downloading 50GB of source, one ends up downloading only 6GB.

My question is, is this enough to build marshmallow ? If so, then why would one ever sync without specify just the current branch and the latest snapshot, if one just wanted to build pure marshmallow, or tweak it ? It seems that anything else would result in historic data which would be useful only for detecting bugs, or assigning blame....

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it is enough as to build it. *May* have problems if you want to do a pull request to AOSP. Check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga) on that.