# Git shallow clone specific version of remote repository

Tags: git, git-clone, git-checkout, git-reset

How can I clone a **specific** version of a certain branch of a remote repository?

I'm working with a very large git tree (Linux Kernel, to be more specific).
In many cases I need to bring the kernel code to a machine where network and file system are very limited.

Usually I need to get just the code of a certain commit on a certain branch, w/o all the leading history.

So, after some digging (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git/9920956#9920956), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga), and in other places) I narrowed it down to this:

```
$ git clone --branch <remote-branch-name> --single-branch --depth 20 http://some-host:8080/some-git-repo.git
$ cd some-git-repo
$ git reset --hard <commit-ID-that-I-need>
```

**Pros**: I'm cloning the only branch that I need, and cloning a very limited amount of history.

**Cons**: Prior to cloning, I need to actually find out which branch has the commit ID that I need, and I also need to estimate how far is the commit from the branch tip and use this number as the "depth" parameter (I used 20 in the example).

So my **question** is: How can I clone a specific version of a certain branch of a remote repository directly, w/o the aforementioned cons?

I found answers saying that it can't be done, but they are rather dated.
Perhaps a newer git has something that allows it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible *unless* the server has a specifc setting in place.

```
uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant
```

See "[Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)" that I mentioned for Git 2.5 and more.

```
git fetch --depth=1 ../testrepo/.git $SHA1
git cat-file commit $SHA1
```