# How do fetch remote branch after I cloned repo with git clone --depth 1

Tags: git

I've repo with long history so I cloned using

```
git clone <url> --depth 1
```

Now I'm in the master branch.

**How do I fetch remote branch called 'feature/my-feature' that was branched 3 commits earlier?**

I've tried:

```
git checkout -b feature/my-feature  origin/feature/my-feature
```

and

```
git fetch -all
```

but I still only see master branch

Comment: How about adding `--no-single-branch` to `git clone`?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335976/1528712 works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need either:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch \
    +refs/heads/feature/my-feature:refs/remotes/origin/feature/myfeature
```

or:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

followed by any of:

```
git fetch
git fetch --depth=<number>
git fetch --deepen=<number>
git fetch --unshallow
```

#### Explanation

When you make a shallow clone, Git adjusts *two* things:

- the default set of branch(es) or tag(s) to be obtained and updated; and
- the depth of the initial fetch.

(Running `git clone` is shorthand, as it were, for doing a long sequence of Git commands that include `git init`, `git remote add`, `git fetch`, and `git checkout`.  There may be a few more commands used, if necessary.)

In particular, `--depth 1` has the side effect of adding `--single-branch`.  If you do not also cancel this out with an explicit `--no-single-branch`, Git will configure the `fetch` line, as if you had run:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/<branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch>
```

This tells later `git fetch` commands to bring over *only* the given `<branch>`, and no others.

A normal (non-shallow, non-single-branch) `git clone` uses the default setting:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

which tells each later `git fetch` to bring over *every* branch.

Then, having configured all future `fetch` operations to be single-branch, the shallow clone fetches with your specified `--depth`, which inserts special "graft" entries using a file named `.git/shallow`.  These affect the overall usefulness of the clone (but much less so in any modern Git); for more about this, see [Is it safe to shallow clone with --depth 1, create commits, and pull updates again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941889/1256452)  For here, though, note that this *does not* retain the `--depth` number.  It just cuts short the initial fetch.  The behavior of future fetches, especially those that use a different reference name, is hard to predict from this.

If you run `git fetch --unshallow`, Git will find all the shallow cut-offs and re-fetch all history from before this point.  Then Git removes the special `.git/shallow` file entirely, and the clone behaves like a non-shallow clone.  This is independent of whether the clone behaves like a `--single-branch` clone.

If you run `git fetch` with a specific `--depth` or `--deepen`, Git will make new shallow cut-offs as needed to set the depth to the number you specify, or increase any existing shallow cut-offs by the number you specify.  If there are multiple branches, the relationship between their various cut-offs is complicated (it's all based on graph walking and without code inspection or testing, it's hard to say how Git will behave in some tricky cases).

Comment: Finally, an answer! This should have been the accepted one. Thank you for explaining it much better than other discussions regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

You could try forcing it by specifying the fetch depth:

```
git fetch --depth=999999
```

depth is the number of commits. Note that when you did a clone, clone actually does a fetch and the depth is the same depth specified in your fetch.

Make that number bigger if needed!

**EDIT**

Also you can/probably-should use deepen - same syntax, but it effectively fetches from where your last specified depth left off.. so its a bit more efficient:

```
git fetch --deepen=999999
```

It might depend on your git version though for that last one....

**EDIT 2**

Just saw this while I was reviewing the git docs....

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

This would be the best way (not sure which version it is implemented in and I have not tried it.... but looks like the thing to use).