# How to checkout a branch only listed in `git ls-remote`?

Tags: git, github

I got a situation that I'm unable to switch to a branch only listed in `git ls-remote`, here is the detail:

I forked an github repoA as repoB, created and pushed my own branches to the repoB in ComputerA, and in ComputerB I clone my forked repo into local disk, added the remote upstream, and tried to switch to the branches I created but failed, I can successfully switch to the same branch in github web page though.

The following result is from repoB in ComputerB.

ls-remote branches:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads
2da2080ea7201fc7928e947dc3214dd89d86c4ba        refs/heads/enable-vim-better-whitespace
433cedd84bba8bcdf3584734906b2c0fd3b6dc3a        refs/heads/fix-lsp-cache-dir
ff65e1cd687d0c144e98b09e4d7a164f8b6bfd3e        refs/heads/gh-pages
17e53cf01badebc2abef7df375903da71bf884d8        refs/heads/master
7b8f8a2dccb0715ff1c1c411abf40b2ff6cec30b        refs/heads/vim-plug
26b8a0ba594af1068997c70c4ef0f503571557b3        refs/heads/vundle
```

list branches:

```
$ git branch
  abc
* master

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  upstream/gh-pages
  upstream/master
  upstream/vim-plug
  upstream/vundle

$ git branch -a
  abc
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/gh-pages
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/vim-plug
  remotes/upstream/vundle
```

The branch `abc` is a local branch I haven't pushed yet.

and I tried several methods to switch to branch such as `fix-lsp-cache-dir` like

```
$ git checkout fix-lsp-cache-dir
error: pathspec 'fix-lsp-cache-dir' did not match any file(s) known to gi

$ git checkout -t origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir
fatal: 'origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir' is not a commit and a branch 'fix-lsp-cache-dir' cannot be created from it
```

I tried google, but all of the suggested methods failed.

So what can I do to switch to the branch only list in `git ls-remote`

Comment: Can you show the remote urls (git remote -v)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I already added remote upstream, original url and upstream url are different. and I can sync from the remote upstream and pull from original url.

Comment: i meant can you edit them into the Q.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Do you need those links? I don't think those urls matter in here.

Comment: Well it may if fetching didnt work—theres basically 4 different repos here and tracking down which one has which branches... clearly comp B doesn’t have them, so I’m curious if the remote its fetching from does (have you tried fetch —all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335936/how-to-checkout-a-branch-only-listed-in-git-ls-remote#comment101165880_57335936) that you have multiple *remotes*, `origin` and `upstream`.  This interferes with—well, *may* interfere with—a Git feature that people often don't know they're depending on: `git checkout`'s so-called *DWIM mode*.  That's not the problem *yet*, but we might as well address it (in the long section below).

You mentioned in a [*second* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335936/how-to-checkout-a-branch-only-listed-in-git-ls-remote#comment101162918_57335976) that `git config -l` includes this output:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This is *not* the normal setting for a typical standard clone with an `origin`.  The normal setting is:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The setting you have is the norm if you originally ran `git clone --single-branch`, or `git clone --depth=...` (which implies `--single-branch`).

To make things work conveniently, you will need to change, or add to, your `remote.origin.fetch` setting.  For instance, if you first change it to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` (see [VonC's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335976/1256452)), you can then run:

```
git fetch origin
```

followed by:

```
git checkout -t origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir
```

or even just:

```
git checkout fix-lsp-cache-dir
```

This shortest method will always work if you have just the *one* remote `origin`.  It will *sometimes fail* if you have *more than one remote*, in which case, you need to use the either the slightly longer `git checkout -t origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir`, or a separate `git branch` command, to create your own branch name `fix-lsp-cache-dir`.

No matter what, you will need one `git fetch` that fetches from `origin` first.  You can name `origin` explicitly in your `git fetch`, or use one of the options that fetches from *all* remotes (`git fetch --all` or `git remote update`, though using `git remote` strays into new territory that brings in many new options).

#### Long: what's going on, behind the scenes

To make sense out of all of this, you need to know all about:

- *branch names*, with which you're already familiar but are internally stored with `refs/heads/` stuck on the front (as you're seeing with `git ls-remote`);
- *remote-tracking names*—Git calls this *remote-tracking branch names* but they're not actually *branch* names, so I prefer to drop that word from the middle: they are internally stored with `refs/remotes/` stuck on the front, followed by the remote name itself;
- *remotes*, which are short strings like `origin` and `upstream` that, if nothing else—usually there's something else too—store a URL;
- *refs* or *references*, which are the long forms of branch names, tag names (`refs/tags/*`), remote-tracking names, and other less-common names like `refs/notes/*` and `refs/stash`;
- *refspecs*, which are mostly just pairs of refs separated by a colon `:` and optionally prefixed by a plus sign `+`; and last,
- `git checkout`'s "DWIM mode" feature.  DWIM stands for *Do What I Mean* (as opposed to what I typed in).  This particular acronym goes back to Xerox PARC and Warren Teitelman: see [Eric Raymond's Jargon File entry](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html) and [the Wikipedia article on Teitelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Teitelman).

#### Refs, refspecs, and remotes

Really, you already know about refs.  They're just the *full names* of each of the various kinds of reference.  They let commands like `git fetch` know whether they are dealing with a branch name (`refs/heads/master`) or a remote-tracking name (`refs/remotes/origin/master`) or whatever, if they even care.<sup>1</sup>

The simplest form of *refspec* is just a pair of refs with a colon.  The name on the left is a *source* and the name on the right is a *destination*.  For `git fetch`, the *source* part means: *Using the same stuff you saw in `git ls-remote` output, find the name and value in the repository I'm fetching from.*  The *destination* part means *create or update the destination name in my own repository.*

The leading plus sign, if it appears, sets the `--force` flag for any updates that occur *because of* that refspec.  Hence:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

is a refspec saying: *Grab their `master` branch, and use that to create or update my `origin/master` remote-tracking name.  Force this update if needed.*  You'll get any new commits they have on *their* `master`, then create-or-update your `origin/master`.  You'll do this update to your own `origin/master` even if that means some commits "fall off" your `origin/master` in the process (`--force`).

I mentioned that remotes pack a bit more than *just* a URL.  Each remote lists some number of *default fetch refspecs*.  Usually it's just one, but usually that one is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<remote>/*
```

with the *`remote`* part filled in.  This particular refspec says: *Take all of their branch names*—all the strings that match `refs/heads/*`—*and create or update, forcibly, all of my corresponding remote-tracking names.*  The corresponding names for remote `origin` are `refs/remotes/origin/*`, so that's what appears here.

Single-branch clones work by the simple expedient of using the single branch name in the refspec.  Now your `git fetch` doesn't create or update the rest of your potential remote-tracking names.  Fix that, and your `git fetch` *will* create or update the rest of your remote-tracking names.

Note that using `refs/heads/*` enables one more feature: `--prune`.  Add `--prune` to your `git fetch` command—or set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration—and `git fetch` will not only create or update the right set of remote-tracking names, but *also* **delete** any left-over remote-tracking names that no longer have a source.

For instance, if the Git on `origin` has a branch named `X` for a short while, and you run `git fetch`, your Git creates your own `origin/X`.  But then whoever controls the Git on origin *removes* branch `X`.  If you don't have pruning enabled, you continue to carry `origin/X`: your Git *created and updated it* while it exists, but now that it doesn't, your Git does nothing about that.  Enable pruning, and your Git says to itself: *Aha, I have a leftover junk `origin/X`!  I'll snip it off automatically.*  Prune should probably be the default, with a "don't-prune" option, but it isn't.

---

<sup>1</sup>Fetch actually does care, because of a bunch of magic weird stuff it tries to do with tags.

---

#### Checkout's "DWIM mode", and when and why it fails with two or more remotes

When you first clone a Git repository (without `--single-branch`), your own Git gets *remote-tracking names* for *every* branch in the `origin` repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git/
```

gives you five remote-tracking names for the five branches in the Git repository over on GitHub, for instance.

As the *last step* of this `git clone`, your Git effectively<sup>2</sup> runs `git checkout master`.  **At this stage** you don't *have* a branch named `master`.  In fact, you have no branch names at all!  So how can `git checkout` check it out?  How can:

```
git checkout <name>
```

ever work, when there are no branch names at all?

The answer is that `git checkout` actually *creates* your branch name `master`.  See the sidebar below as well (formatted as an extra section since I can't do real sidebars).  When `git checkout` is given what seems like it could be a branch name, but isn't, it looks at *all* of your remote-tracking names: `origin/master`, `origin/maint`, `origin/next`, and so on, if you are using the Git repository for Git, for instance.  If *exactly one* name matches, then your Git acts as though you actually ran:

```
git checkout -t origin/<name>
```

which tells `git checkout`: *Create the branch, setting the remote-tracking name as its upstream.*  Now that the name exists, *now* `git checkout` can check it out.

**This process fails if there are two or more matching names.**  Suppose, for instance, that you *don't* have `fix-lsp-cache-dir` as a *branch* name, but you *do* have, in your own Git repository, `origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir` *and* `upstream/fix-lsp-cache-dir`.  You run:

```
git checkout fix-lsp-cache-dir
```

which doesn't find `fix-lsp-cache-dir` but does find `origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir` and `upstream/fix-lsp-cache-dir`.  It found not one but *two* remote-tracking names.  Should it use the `origin` one, or the `upstream` one?  It doesn't know.

At this point, `git checkout` simply gives up and says that it has no idea what you mean by `fix-lsp-cache-dir`.  So now you need, e.g., `git checkout -t origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir`, which is an explicit instruction: *Look up the remote-tracking name `origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir`, use that to create `fix-lsp-cache-dir`, then check out `fix-lsp-cache-dir`.*  That supplies the answer about *which* upstream remote-tracking name to use, and at the same time, what *branch* name to create.

---

<sup>2</sup>I say "effectively" here because the code inside `git clone` that does this, does not literally run `git checkout`, nor bother with a lot of the DWIM mode stuff: it knows exactly what it's put into the repository already and can cheat.  If you split your `git clone` into a series of separate commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch
git checkout master
```

you will literally run `git checkout master` and invoke the DWIM mode I'm describing.

(Mental exercise: compare and contrast Git's branch DWIM and your smartphone's autocorrect.)

#### Extra-long sidebar: how Git branches really work

Every Git branch name—in fact, every Git *reference*—really just stores one hash ID.  For branch names—and by implication, remote-tracking names—the hash ID is constrained to be a *commit* hash ID; some other refs have more flexibility, e.g., tag names can point to any of Git's four internal object types.

The thing is, when we say "branch `master`", or "this commit is on branch `master`", or anything along those lines, we often don't mean *one particular commit*, even though the actual branch *name* `master` is only able to *identify* one particular commit.  How this works explains a lot about Git.

In capsule form:

- To *create* a branch, we write the hash ID of some existing, valid commit into a name that did not exist before.
- To *update* a branch, we write the hash ID of some existing, valid commit into a name that already existed.  It no longer identifies the commit it remembered a moment ago.  Now it identifies the one we picked instead.

No matter what, though, we start with a commit hash ID.  So in a sense, it's the *commits* that matter, not the branch names (though of course we want those too!).

In Git, every commit is identified by its own unique, big ugly hash ID.  For instance, one commit in the Git repository for Git is `9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0`.  (This is a commit that is in preparation for Git version 2.23, but is not any particular release.)  These hash IDs are fine for *Git* to use—it's a computer program, and it won't make mistakes in using these things as keys in a key-value database—but they're pretty useless to mere humans.  We do better with *names*, like `master`.  If we create our branch name `master` and make that name *mean* "commit `9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0`", we can run:

```
git log master
```

or:

```
git diff my-branch master
```

or whatever.  The name `master` will pick out commit `9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0` each time.  But then how does Git know that commit `8619522ad1670ea82c0895f2bfe6c75e06df32e7`—another random-looking hash ID—is the commit that comes right *before* `master` (`9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0`)?

The answer is that `8619522ad1670ea82c0895f2bfe6c75e06df32e7` is stored *inside* `9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0`:

```
$ git cat-file -p 9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 33bba5e893986797fd68c4515bfafd709c6f69e5
parent 8619522ad1670ea82c0895f2bfe6c75e06df32e7
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1563561263 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1563561263 -0700

The sixth batch

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

The `parent` line here gives the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.

Every Git commit—well, *almost* every one—has at least one *parent*.<sup>3</sup>  Git can move one step backwards in history, from a commit to its parent.  The parent itself has another parent, so Git can move one more step.  The path obtained by moving, step by step, from commit to parent, *is* the history in Git repository.

We can draw this, for simple linear chains, by pretending for a moment that instead of big ugly hash IDs, Git uses one letter names for each commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The *last* commit in the chain is commit `H`.  That's the hash ID stored under the name `master`.  We say that `master` *points to* `H`.  `H` in turn stores the hash ID for `G`, so we say that `H` points to `G`.  `G` stores the hash ID for `F`, so `G` points to `F`.  `F` points to `F`'s parent.  This continues all the way down the line until we hit a commit that *doesn't* have a parent, such as the first commit ever for this repository ... and those are the commits that are "on" branch `master`.

To add a new commit, we have Git save a snapshot of all of our source files, add our name and email address and other stuff that `git log` shows, use the actual hash ID of commit `H` as the *parent*, and write out a new commit.  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, but we'll just call it `I`.  Then Git simply overwrites the name `master` with this new hash ID:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--master
```

and the `master` branch is now one commit longer.  The *last* commit in the chain is called the *tip* commit.  We know—or find—the tip commits in a Git repository by reading the hash IDs from the branch names.

**The branch name `master` simply identifies the *last* commit in the chain.**  The various Git commands that move branch names, or remote-tracking names, around, such as `git reset` or `git branch -f` or—for remote-tracking names—`git fetch`—are really just making the names point to one specific commit.

If we can start at the *new* tip, and use the internal, backwards-pointing arrows to find the *old* tip, then all we have done is *add* some commit(s) to the branch.  When we use `git commit` to create a commit, that's just what it does: it creates one new commit, which becomes the tip, and which has the old tip as its parent.

When we use `git fetch` and we get, say, three or five new commits for our remote-tracking name `origin/master`, the *last* of these—the tip—leads back, eventually, to where our `origin/master` pointed *before* we ran `git fetch`.  So the new commits are just newly added to the `origin/master` remote-tracking name.

Git calls this kind of name update, that only *adds* things, a *fast-forward*.  You can do fast-forwards with `git fetch`, updating your remote-tracking names, and with `git push`, giving new commits to some other Git and having them update their *branch* names.  In both cases, your Git and/or their Git have not *lost* any commits, because starting at the new tip and working backwards, you or they arrive at the old tip.

You can also—with a few extra wrinkles—do a fast-forward with `git merge`.  If `git merge` does a fast-forward instead of a merge, it's used commits that you *already have*, without actually making any new commits.  For instance, after `git fetch origin`, you might have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/master
```

Here you actually are on your own `master`, indicated by attaching the special name `HEAD` to the name `master`.  Your Git can now do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge by *moving* the name `master` so that it points to commit `J`, and doing a `git checkout` of commit `J`, all at the same time:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

That's what a *fast-forward merge* is: it's really not a merge at all, but just a `git checkout` that also drags the current branch name forward, the same way that `git fetch` fast-forwarded your `origin/master` a moment ago.

The `--force` flag is needed when the operation is *not* a fast-forward.  For instance, suppose you just did the above, so now `master` and `origin/master` both identify commit `J`.  Meanwhile, whoever controls the repository over at `origin` says: *Oh crap!  Commit `J` is bad!  I'm throwing it out with `git reset --hard` and adding a new commit `K` instead!*  Now you run `git fetch` again and get:

```
          K   <-- origin/master
         /
...--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

You *still have* commit `J`: it's on *your* `master`.  *They* tried to toss out commit `J` (whatever its actual hash ID is—your Git and their Git agree on its hash ID).  Your `origin/master` now points to `K`, and `K`'s parent is `I`, not `J`.  Your `origin/master` was just *force-updated*.

You'll see this in `git fetch` output:

```
$ git fetch
...
 + a83509d9fc...0ddebcb508 pu          -> origin/pu  (forced update)
```

The `pu` branch, in the Git repository for Git, is one that everyone agrees gets force-updated regularly.  So my `origin/pu` used to identify `a83509d9fc`, but now it identifies `0ddebcb508`.  Note that `+`, the words `(forced update)`, and the fact that there are *three*, not two, dots between the two hash IDs: those are the three ways that `git fetch` announces that my `origin/pu` has just been force-updated.  I can now do this:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --count a83509d9fc...0ddebcb508
79  214
```

which tells me 79 commits were dropped (from my old `origin/pu`) and 214 commits were added (to my new updated `origin/pu`).  I don't actually *care* in this case, but if I did for some reason, I can see what they did over at `origin`.

(Slightly more useful:

```
$ git rev-list --count master..origin/master
210
```

tells me that there are 210 new commits that I can bring into my `master` now.  To actually *look at* those commits, I probably want `git log`.)

---

<sup>3</sup>A commit with *no* parents is defined as a *root commit*.  That's the kind of commit you make when you make the very first commit in a new, totally-empty Git repository.  This first commit *can't* have a parent, so it doesn't.

A commit with *two or more* parents is defined as a *merge commit*.  That's the kind of commit that `git merge` typically makes.  The *first* parent is business as usual; any additional parents tell Git which commit(s) were merged.

Comment: Wow, that is really a long explanation, thank you for your kindness. The problem is I did `git clone` the repo with `--depth=1`, even after that I `git pull --unshallow` in the repo, I believe it is still `single-branch`. I learnt a lot from your reply. And I got another question, how can I pull/fetch all remote branches so I can switch after I already `git clone --depth=1`, I tried google, but `git pull/fetch --all` don't work, the only solution works is https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714718/1528712, but that is not convenient, is there any git command with options. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only have to update the `git config remote.origin.fetch` setting once (for each remote that has a single-branch setting, but that's probably just `origin` in your case). That changes your clone from `--single-branch` to normal. (The `--unshallow` step converts your clone from shallow to full, and you can do these in either order.)

Comment: Although a simple ```git fetch origin``` made the branch available to me, I really like your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to `git fetch` first.

Check your git config remote.origin does show a [fetch refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) like:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That will import `fix-lsp-cache-dir` into your repository, and you will be able to checkout that branch.
Checkout or... [soon `git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

The [OP CodyChan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1528712/codychan) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335936/how-to-checkout-a-branch-only-listed-in-git-ls-remote/57335976?noredirect=1#comment101162918_57335976):

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

That would only fetch master, nothing else.

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

That should fix it.

Comment: I did `git fetch` in the `I tried google, but all of the suggested methods failed.` part, and I just did it again, the fetch part in my `git config -l` for this repo is: `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`, and `git checkout fix-lsp-cache-dir` or `git checkout -t origin/fix-lsp-cache-dir` still fail.

Comment: It could be that you need to fetch from "upstream" (fetch defaults to origin if you don't specify a remote)

Comment: @CodyChan your refspec is made to only fetch master. Change it by what I recommend, and you will fetch every remote branches.

Comment: @VonC Thanks you, `git clone --depth=1` is the reason as @torek replied, your suggestion is the only solution I found that can fix the problem for a repo already cloned with --depth=1, I'm wondering is there any other simpler solution such as git command with options?

Comment: @CodyChan If you don't want to change the refspec permanently, you can change it just for the fetch phase, with `git -c remote.origin.fetch="+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" fetch`