# Can you shallow clone 2 branches using git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I'd like to shallow clone part of a repository: just 1 feature branch (including all of the commits since branching from `main`) and a few commits on `main` before that.

I have tried `git clone $repo --depth=N --branch=$feature` which does correctly check out a shallow clone of $feature, and assuming I pick depth to be large enough goes back to the branch point.

What's the incantation to pull in main as well?

Essentially I want to be able to do:

```
git clone --branch=$feature
BASE=$(git merge-base $feature origin/main)
echo git rev-parse $BASE^
echo git rev-parse $BASE^^
echo git rev-parse $BASE^^^
```

to tell me the SHA1s of the few commits that happened just before branching.

Comment: I think you would need to use the `git clone --depth=N --no-single-branch` option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816633/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+shallow+clone+multiple+branches