# Is possible to push the non-pushed commits if the git files contain corrupt loose objects?

Tags: git, recovery

`git status` outputs the following:

```
# On branch master
error: corrupt loose object '1e2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d'
fatal: loose object 1e2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d (stored in .git/objects/1e/2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d) is corrupt
```

I have 12 non pushed commits. I can see them in `git log`.

Is there any hope to push them?

`git push` outputs:

```
error: corrupt loose object '1e2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d'
fatal: loose object 1e2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d (stored in .git/object/1e/2dc6d8b6eec682f3ecc9dd879445fea5d6a34d) is corrupt
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.com:username/reponame.git'
```

---

Before having these corrupted files I run:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\s\+$//g'
```

(in the git repo directory)

This affected the `.git` files.

---

Update: I tried the [VonC's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20868539/1420197) running the following commands:

```
cd ~
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git
Cloning into 'reponame'...
remote: Counting objects: 1561, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (853/853), done.
remote: Total 1561 (delta 966), reused 1067 (delta 642)
Receiving objects: 100% (1561/1561), 223.80 KiB | 94.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (966/966), done.
Checking connectivity... done
$ cd reponame/
$ $ git remote add yourLocalRemoteName /home/user/corupted/git/repository/folder
$ git pull yourLocalRemoteName
fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect what we discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and:

- clone your BitBucket repo again
- add in that new clone a remote referencing your current local clone

  ```
    git remote add corrupt/path/to/your/first/cloned/repo
  ```
- `git pull corrupt`, and then `git push`

---

That being said, after using [`git fsck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) for confirmation, you can try and [solve that corrupt object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12571557/6309).
As usual, make a backup of that local repo first.

---

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44272/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-vonc), it turns out that:

- the corrupt repo is a shallow one (cloned that way automatically by a tool).
  That means you can clone it easily, even when you do a `rm .git/shallow`, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989006/6309).
- one way to unshallow a shallow repo is to [unpack a fresh repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972155/6309) and copy over the [`.git/objects/pack`](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/09/git-tip-of-week-objects-and-packfiles.html) folder to the corrupted repo:

  ```
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git repo2
    mkdir packs
    cp repo2/.git/objects/packs/* packs
    cd repos2
    git unpack-objects < ../packs/*.pack
    cd ..
    cp -r repo2/.git/objects/* corrupt/.git/objects/
  ```
- That will remove any error due to legacy unpacked object being corrupted by the `sed` command, but that won't fix the ones done since that clone.

For a corrupted repo, the usual commands are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303681/6309) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object#comment15117533_4263009).
In the end, the OP had:

```
git fsck --full
error: corrupt loose object '3ddb67eb5343e75ac36656c86c4386f8dd117df4'
fatal: loose object 3ddb67eb5343e75ac36656c86c4386f8dd117df4 (stored in .git/objects/3d/db67eb5343e75ac36656c86c4386f8dd117df4) is corrupt
```

(no more:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: sha1 mismatch ...
```

which were because of legacy commit corrupted)

For solving that, one can try and follow "[`Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt)".

---

That being said, if that doesn't pan out, it is easier to at least group all last commits into one:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git repo2
cd repo2
git --work-tree=../corrupt add -A .
git commit -m "last changes"
git push
```

One can try and rebuild all 12 commits, but that isn't obvious to do, especially when multiple modifications are done within one file.

Comment: Can you explain what `yourLocalRemoteName` means?

Comment: I get this error when I run `git pull yourLocalRemoteName`: 

*
`fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`
*

Comment: @IonicăBizău it is just a name for your remote. Replace it by any name you want, like `repo1` for instance.

Comment: @IonicăBizău did you do a `git remote add repo1 /local/path/to/your/first/repo` from within your second local cloned repo?

Comment: Yes, I did... Maybe the path to `.git` folder is required?

Comment: I get the same error even the path is to the `.git` directory.

Comment: @IonicăBizău No: local path to your first repo, not "local path to your first repo / .git". Please edit your question with the *exact* sequence of commands you just typed, and I will fix those.

Comment: @IonicăBizău if you still have the "shallow repo" error, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/7989006/6309.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44272/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-vonc)