# How to deploy create-react-app to github pages? getting "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages, create-react-app

I'm getting an error when trying to **deploy** a create-react-app to GitHub pages

Enabled gh-pages in repo's settings, installed gh-pages dependencies, added scripts to package.json

This is the repo: https://github.com/pablowbk/react-swapi-app

This is how my package.json file looks:

```
    {
      "name": "swapiapp",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "https://pablowbk.github.io/react-swapi-app/",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.6.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      ..., //shortened for posting
      "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
      }
    }
```

and when I run "npm run deploy":

link to screenshot -> [npm run deploy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw7xx.jpg)
(can't post imgs yet, sorry...)

Comment: You sure your repo isn't private?

Comment: How would I go about changing that?

Comment: In the settings for the repo on GitHub, you can set it to private / public.

Comment: Seems to be public. This is what I get in settings:

Comment: Make this repository private

Please upgrade your plan to make this repository private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be from the nature of your `git` project. Its complaining that your project is a `shallow repository`. Please fix that first & try. Read more about [`shallow repository`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770532/error-when-cloning-git-shallow-repository).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try creating a new repo then

Comment: I read about shallow repos and even tried 'git fetch --unshallow' to no avail. Ended up creating a clean new repo, copied the contents over from the original repository and followd the install gh-pages steps. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Github pages will not execute any serverside code. You may only upload static files (html,css,js, images, etc.).

In order to have a hosted backend you should look for another service like Google Cloud, AWS Lambda, Heroku, etc.

Comment: React is not server side code.